# How to install TP-LINK T2UH Wireless adapter Driver (Ralink mt7610u)

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, ralink, adapter

I recently got a wireless adapter (TP-Link Archer T2UH V1). After plugging it in, I found out that the drivers for Linux are not native on Ubuntu. They do, however, have the drivers available for download (in the form of compilable/ makefile). What I am not sure of is how to install these drivers. I know that I need to build the drivers, place things where they need to be, and tie things together with the kernel. I am not sure how to do this, however, and need some help.

TL;DR: I need to know the terminal commands to install these drivers.

Driver/Device info:
http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/Archer-T2UH.html#Driver

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Connect to internet by wire, then run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/Myria-de/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.git
cd mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
make
sudo make install
sudo mkdir -p /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA
sudo cp RT2870STA.dat  /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat
```

Reboot.

The dongle should work. The only problem is that you will have to re-install it after each kernel upgrade.

But if you keep the driver folder `mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916`, then it will be quite easy.

You will need to run only

```
cd mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
make
sudo make install
```

after a kernel upgrade.

It is also possible to install it using DKMS. In this case it will rebuild automatically on kernel upgrades.

Comment: // , Ugh, really ? Every kernel upgrade? I'm just going to return it.

Comment: It is possible to install the driver using DKMS. This way you will not need to re-install after kernel updates.

Comment: @Pilot6 How do I install w/ DKMS? I tried the above method and it isn't working.  Network Manager says device not managed.

Comment: I still want to know how to get it working with DKMS. Also, thoughts on whether to use the fork you linked, or chenhaiq's repo?

Comment: It can be installed with DKMS as any other kernel module. There is a lot of guides in the net.

Comment: sorry this might sound like a silly question (i'm new), how do you guys know that isn't some virus or something that you are installing? ie the driver is written by some random folks and not the manufacturer

Comment: You can see the source code.

Comment: @Pilot6 true, but i bet of all the folks who installed this nobody has looked at it.. in theory that's true with all open source but in this case it seems particularly true.. no?

Comment: Did not work for me, broke my distribution and lead to freezes on login screen. Be careful when you try this.

Comment: @Zelphir It is easy to uninstall the driver. So it can't "break your distribution".

Comment: @Pilot6 I take it back: Only when I plug in the device it freezes my system. So you are right. Unfortunately still no joy =(

Comment: @Zelphir You can ask another question regarding this problem.

Comment: On my system it began to work only when I copied file to `/etc/RT2870STA/`

Comment: @Orient I took the path from the github source.

Comment: On Ubuntu 17.04 with kernel this fails: `error: ‘IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS’ undeclared here (not in a function)`

Comment: One more fresh driver for this shit https://github.com/xtknight/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes

Comment: And one more: https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u

Comment: And one more: https://github.com/Hygens/mt7610u_ubuntu_1610

Answer (score 9):

I have a TP-Link T2U Wi-Fi adapter and I was in struggle to find a working driver for Ubuntu 18.10. All the drivers, original and modified, was for previous version of the kernel but nothing useful for the 4.15 kernel. After a painful morning I found a working link to run the TP-Link T2U on the latest kernel.

Here is the link: [Trying to fix the MT7610U chipset driver - GitHub](https://github.com/xtknight/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes)

After following the instructions everything worked! I found the link on [TP-LINK Archer T2U v2 - WikiDevi](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_Archer_T2U_v2).

If you would install the driver you will need to compile the source. To do this you will need install git and clone the repository in your home directory.

```
sudo apt install git
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/xtknight/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes.git
cd mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes
```

You can avoid to write the whole directory just type the first letters, for example, `mt7610`, and press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

After these steps the device should work. If you want the driver to work after the updating the kernel I advise to follow the next steps that includes the *dkms* utility. You will need to work in the directory "mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes" otherwise the process will not work.

```
sudo apt-get install dkms  
sudo cp -R . /usr/src/mt7610u_sta-1.0
sudo dkms add mt7610u_sta/1.0
sudo dkms build mt7610u_sta/1.0
sudo dkms install mt7610u_sta/1.0
```

I hope to be useful for the further development of this OS.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 kernel 4.18.0-24-generic. Thank you @NwalmeThule

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18.04 4.15.0.54-generic. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This worked for me on Mint 19.1 kernel 4.15.0.55. Thanks