# Problems after install TP-LINK T2UH AC600 Wireless adapter Driver (Ralink mt7610u)

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, adapter

help me!
I follow the steps on that post:
[How to install TP-LINK T2UH Wireless adapter Driver (Ralink mt7610u)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674116/how-to-install-tp-link-t2uh-wireless-adapter-driver-ralink-mt7610u#new-answer)
But, my dongle only work on 2.4Ghz and not 5Ghz, what I do?
My kernel is:
4.2.0-30-generic
My Ubuntu is 14.04.04 (LTS).

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ nano ~/mt7610u*/os/linux/rt_linux.c


@@ -1086,8 +1086,8 @@ int RtmpOSFileRead(RTMP_OS_FD osfd, char *pDataPtr, int readLen)
    if (osfd->f_op && osfd->f_op->read) {
        return osfd->f_op->read(osfd, pDataPtr, readLen, &osfd->f_pos);
    } else {
-        DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("no file read method\n"));
-        return -1;
+        DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("no file read method, using vfs_read\n"));
+        return vfs_read(osfd, pDataPtr, readLen, &osfd->f_pos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer? Because it just looks like a unified diff to me. While that may be part of a valid answer it is not enough on its own. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)