# try to install tp-link wireless adapter (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: drivers, usb, 16.04, adapter

I'm new in Ubuntu 16.04, and I don't understand how I download the driver to my adapter from http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/Archer-T2UH.html

I can't install it.

Can someone help me to install the adapter? Please tell me also the commands on terminal

lsusb-

```
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 05ac:12a0 Apple, Inc. iPhone 4S
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0000:0538  
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04ca:0022 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I also try this [How to install TP-LINK T2UH Wireless adapter Driver (Ralink mt7610u)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674116/how-to-install-tp-link-t2uh-wireless-adapter-driver-ralink-mt7610u)

and is not fix the problem. Please explain me what to do and how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can install a driver from my PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mt7610u-dkms
```

This PPA supports xenial with the 4.4 kernel.

Comment: I've installed the package, but there is no mt7610u module installed. `modprobe mt7610u` gives an error: `modprobe: FATAL: Module mt7610u not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic`.  `lsmod mt7610u` is empty.  `locate mt7610u.ko` is also empty. `dkms status` output is `mt7610u, 0.2, 4.4.0-31-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)`

Comment: The module name is `mt7610u_sta`

Comment: Can it interact with NetworkManager?

Comment: Yes, it can....