# How to install TP LINK T2U Archer 600 Wireless adapter on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, 18.04, tp-link

I buy the TP Link T2U AC600 wireless adaptor because they 'have' linux driver, but i try to install it and until now nothing. My machine have a Ubuntu 18.04 and the oficial drive work until kernel 3.16. The information about my machine:
`lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1532:0110 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 22b8:2e25 Motorola PCS 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1ea7:0011  
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0951:16a1 Kingston Technology 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux lowe 4.15.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 10 17:58:07 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I try all this bellow and nothing works. Attention the last command is where the error appears:

1. [mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916](https://github.com/chenhaiq/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916), get a error on `make` command:

> git clone https://github.com/chenhaiq/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.git
>   cd mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
>   make

```
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/mnt/downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/mnt/downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/mnt/downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/mnt/downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-32-generic'
Makefile:403: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

2. [archer-t2u-ubuntu-installer](https://github.com/ivannieto/archer-t2u-ubuntu-installer)
   , work for ubuntu 17.10. I try to install on ubuntu 18.04 and get a error on `python3 t2u-driver-installer.py`

> git clone --branch 2.0.0 git@github.com:ivannieto/archer-t2u-ubuntu-installer.git
>   cd archer-t2u-ubuntu-installer/ && python3 t2u-driver-installer.py

```
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/mnt/downloads/archer-t2u-ubuntu-installer/driver-files/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o' failed    
make[2]: *** [/mnt/downloads/archer-t2u-ubuntu-installer/driver-files/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/mnt/downloads/archer-t2u-ubuntu-installer/driver-files/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/mnt/downloads/archer-t2u-ubuntu-installer/driver-files/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-32-generic'
Makefile:393: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
insmod: ERROR: could not load module mt7650u_sta.ko: No such file or directory
*************************

Your computer should be restarted now.
Please close all running programs and restart manually when you're done.
An executable will be installed to enable or disable the adapter.
Just run in your terminal '$ sudo t2u-driver'.
```

3. [TP-link TL-WN725N driver for 18.04 version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047832/tp-link-tl-wn725n-driver-for-18-04-version?rq=1), that is not the correct version for adapter but i try:

> git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
>   cd rtl8188eu
>   make all
>   sudo make install
>   sudo insmod 8188eu.ko

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module 8188eu.ko: Required key not available
```

4. [Installing Tp-Link AC600 on Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64 [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674116/how-to-install-tp-link-t2uh-wireless-adapter-driver-ralink-mt7610u), this is the most popular thread about the adapter, but not work too, And yes, i install dmks and build essential.

> git clone https://github.com/Myria-de/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.git
>   cd mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
>   make

```
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/mnt/downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/mnt/downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/mnt/downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/mnt/downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-32-generic'
Makefile:403: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

5. [try to install tp-link wireless adapter (Ubuntu 16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801518/try-to-install-tp-link-wireless-adapter-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1), that PPA repository does not work on Ubuntu 18.04 and break the apt update.
6. [Hygens/mt7610u_ubuntu_1610](https://github.com/Hygens/mt7610u_ubuntu_1610), but just work for 16.04

> git clone https://github.com/Hygens/mt7610u_ubuntu_1610.git
>   cd mt7610u_ubuntu_1610/
>   make

```
In function ‘memcpy’, inlined from ‘rt_ioctl_iwaplist’ at /mnt/downloads/mt7610u_ubuntu_1610/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.c:696:2: ./include/linux/string.h:340:4: error: call to ‘__read_overflow2’ declared with attribute error: detected read beyond size of object passed as 2nd parameter __read_overflow2();
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/mnt/downloads/mt7610u_ubuntu_1610/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/mnt/downloads/mt7610u_ubuntu_1610/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/mnt/downloads/mt7610u_ubuntu_1610/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/mnt/downloads/mt7610u_ubuntu_1610/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-32-generic'
Makefile:405: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

I search more others solutions but i have the limit of 8 links.
Thank you for help!

Comment: did you run `sudo t2u-driver`

Comment: is this really a dupe? the answer at the other question is "get different hardware" is that really the solution????

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte, I try to run `sudo t2u-driver` but the system does not find the adapter.

Comment: did you try using that ppa in my answer? if that doesn't work, let me know

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte The answer in the dupe is actually, “No, you cannot compile *any* driver for this device in any modern kernel version and so I recommend that you get a different device.”

Comment: man that is a real bummer.... hopefully it will get sorted in the future

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in UEFI/BIOS and try https://github.com/sgruszka/mt76x0  then `sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/mediatek && cd /lib/firmware/mediatek` then `sudo cp https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/mediatek/mt7610u.bin` reboot

Comment: https://linux-thai.blogspot.com/2018/10/install-tp-link-ac600-archer-t2u-driver.html