# wireless driver is not working correctly

Tags: networking, wireless, broadcom

After an update a few days ago, my wireless driver is not working anymore, unfortunately. I tried several things, but it all didn't work and now i dont have any clue what to do. maybe someone can help me.

Basic info:
Ubuntu 14.04. Ethernet is working. When ethernet unplugged, no wifi connections show up. Before the update everything was working fine.
I bought a wifi USB adaptor, however this also didnt work. (TP-Link T2U)

I run a scripted to provide some information (from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) ):
[wireless info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23051692/)

I installed an additional driver (bcmwl-kernel-source
) as explained [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214110). This did work till the update.
Also followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674116/how-to-install-tp-link-t2uh-wireless-adapter-driver-ralink-mt7610u) for the USB adaptor, but also didn't work.
I also tried the live version of 16.04, but neither the USB adaptor nor the internal driver is working.

Can anyone help me and maybe tell what i could try? 
Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
Did the `sudo modprobe wl` code, outcome was:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available

My secure boot is disabled. No clue what this means.

Comment: What is the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe wl`?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules

Comment: Secure Boot is not disabled.

Answer (score 0):

sudo modprobe w1 resulted in

modprobe: FATAL: Module w1 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic