# Cannot Install Tp-Link Archer T2UH

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, ralink

I have been trying to install the driver for the T2UH. I have followed the instruction [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674116/how-to-install-tp-link-t2uh-wireless-adapter-driver-ralink-mt7610u) and it does not work. System errors on load mentioning the modemmanager crashing and it cannot find any networks. lsusb output is `148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp.`

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.1. I have tried updating everything, restarting, etc. I am on kernel 4.4.0-34. I have also tried, on a separate, clean install (same system), on Unity Ubuntu and same result.

I have tried plugging it into both USB 3 and USB 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found an answer. By following the steps [posted by Pilot6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674116/how-to-install-tp-link-t2uh-wireless-adapter-driver-ralink-mt7610u) and then running `service network-manager restart` I was able to get it to work.