# TP-Link T2U (AC600) usb WLAN adapter driver on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, make

I'm trying to compile [this driver](https://github.com/Myria-de/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/) for the TP-Link T2U usb WLAN adapter on Ubuntu 16.10.
Trying to perform *make* command I get the following error:

```
    /home/iks/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/cfg80211.h:35:49: error: ‘IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS’ undeclared here (not in a function)
  struct ieee80211_supported_band Cfg80211_bands[IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS];
```

The solution from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674116/how-to-install-tp-link-t2uh-wireless-adapter-driver-ralink-mt7610u) contains exactly the same installation manual as in the repository and therefore doesn't help.

Could someone help me to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install TP-LINK T2UH Wireless adapter Driver (Ralink mt7610u)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/674116/how-to-install-tp-link-t2uh-wireless-adapter-driver-ralink-mt7610u)

Comment: I'm getting this error following exactly the manual from http://askubuntu.com/questions/674116/how-to-install-tp-link-t2uh-wireless-adapter-driver-ralink-mt7610u

Comment: Please test the answer below and accept it if it works.

Answer (score 3):

The circa-2013 driver file is too old for your 4.8.0-xx kernel, try this instead:

```
git clone https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u.git
cd mt7610u
make
sudo cp firmware/*  /lib/firmware
sudo insmod mt7610u.ko
```

Please tell us how it went as we will have additional steps.

Comment: Until make install everything was perfect. Install results in 'code No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.  and modprobe: 'code FATAL: Module mt7610 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-32-generic' But somehow I see the MediaTek Wi-Fi device in the Network Manager, though it says "Device not ready" and its grayed out.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: Here is the resultinsmod: ERROR: could not load module mt7610u: No such file or directory

Comment: Were you in the correct directory when you did the command: `cd ~/mt7610u` Check if the file is there: `ls` Now try to load it: `sudo insmod mt7610u.ko`

Comment: ok, the problem was in the *.ko extension, I forgot to add it, I'm sorry. Now the insmod went without any output.

Comment: Awesome! And now do you have available connections in Network Manager?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It appeared in Network Manager as Wifi Network(MediaTek WiFi) but it says "device not ready" and its grayed out. No possibility to see or scan networks.

Comment: May we see a log? `cat /var/log/syslog |  grep -e mt76 -e wl` As the output may be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Sure [log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23708224/ ) . wlp3s0 is a built-in wlan adapter

Comment: I am quite confident that two different devices attempting to connect at the same time conflict. Why are you trying to activate the tricky and work-in-progress mt7610u instead of the usually reliable Broadcom??

Comment: The reason is 5Ghz band. It is that much crowded on 2.4 around that the wireless connection is almost not working.

Comment: Does the command: sudo iwlist channel` confirm that mt7610u is capble of 5 ghz? If so, before we proceed further, we out to blacklist the driver for the internal.

Comment: I've checked it, yes, it has 5GHz support. Btw, thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: I suggest that you blacklist the driver for the internal device; it can be easily reversed if needed. `echo "blacklist wl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` Reboot and let us see another log as above.

Comment: Everything goes well... until I try to run insmod... then I get the following error: "insmod: ERROR: could not insert module mt7610u.ko: Unknown symbol in module"... Any ideas on how to fix it?

Kernel: 4.13.0-16-generic

Comment: @danielfranca I don’t believe there is *any* way to get this to work on any kernel version that is not now (12/2017) end of life. Sorry.

Comment: I have this: insmod: ERROR: could not insert module mt7610u.ko: Unknown symbol in module

Comment: @MarkSkayff Please see my comment just above yours.

Comment: whats the use of a solution that no longer applies. Maybe there should be a linux kernel marker. Like worked with ...

Comment: @JackGrinningCat  My answer clearly refers to kernel version 4.8. If yoyrs is newer, then this is not for you. In any event, I doubt that there is ANY solution to get an mt7610u working in 4.15 and newer.