# Setting Up MT7610U Wireless Driver

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I've searched all over and am *so close* to finishing this driver install. It's an Archer T2UH, AC600 USB dongle. The machine I'm installing it onto is running Kubuntu 17.04. I've successfully compiled and installed the driver from [this Github repo](https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u) as recommended by chili555 [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865102/tp-link-t2u-ac600-usb-wlan-adapter-driver-on-ubuntu-16-10/865157#865157) as well as other places. I've been fortunate not to have had as many issues as others, as I recognize that this is a tricky driver.

The meat of my problem right now is that I can *see* networks, but I can't connect to any of them. Other people have had issues when connecting multiple adapters, but I am only connected to one at a time. I've tried connecting through NetworkManager's GUI and manually [with WPA Supplicant](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant) (using both `wpa_cli` and a configuration file). The device is blinking green, indicating the drivers must be loaded.

I will include a variety of logs below to help diagnose the problem. Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide.

My USB wifi dongle; via `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

Hardware blocking; via `rfkill list all`

```
2: phy2: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Relevant networking hardware information; via `lshw -class network`:

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 84:16:f9:1c:be:d9
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=RALINK WLAN multicast=yes wireless=Ralink STA
```

Interface status; via `ip link`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp10s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:f0:49:56:8a:f3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DORMANT mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:16:f9:1c:be:d9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

My attempt at connecting to the network manually; via `sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/archerCoolbox5.conf`:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlan0: Trying to associate with a4:2b:b0:fa:40:85 (SSID='CoolBox_5G' freq=5180 MHz)
wlan0: Authentication with a4:2b:b0:fa:40:85 timed out.
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=a4:2b:b0:fa:40:85 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlan0: Trying to associate with a4:2b:b0:fa:40:85 (SSID='CoolBox_5G' freq=5180 MHz)
wlan0: Authentication with a4:2b:b0:fa:40:85 timed out.
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=a4:2b:b0:fa:40:85 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="CoolBox_5G" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="CoolBox_5G"
wlan0: Trying to associate with a4:2b:b0:fa:40:85 (SSID='CoolBox_5G' freq=5180 MHz)
wlan0: Authentication with a4:2b:b0:fa:40:85 timed out.
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=a4:2b:b0:fa:40:85 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="CoolBox_5G" auth_failures=2 duration=23 reason=CONN_FAILED
...
```

Relevant logs from dmesg; via `dmesg`:

```
...
[ 5178.630667] 80211> CFG80211_Scaning ==>
[ 5178.630674] 80211> cfg80211_inform_bss_frame
[ 5179.137074] 80211> CFG80211_Scaning ==>
[ 5179.137084] 80211> cfg80211_inform_bss_frame
[ 5179.359807] 80211> cfg80211_scan_done
[ 5179.360051] 80211> CFG80211_OpsSurveyGet ==>
[ 5179.360055] 80211> busy time = -109729513193472 0
[ 5179.360445] 80211 [CONNECT TEST]> CFG80211_OpsConnect ==>
[ 5179.360448] Groupwise: fac04
[ 5179.360449] Pairwise fac04
[ 5179.360450] Wpa_versions 2
[ 5179.360451] Keymgmt fac02
[ 5179.360452] Auth_type 0
[ 5179.360453] WLAN_CIPHER_SUITE_CCMP...
[ 5179.360454] ConnInfo.KeyLen ===> 0
[ 5179.360455] ConnInfo.KeyIdx ===> 0
[ 5179.360458] 80211> Connect bssid a4:2b:b0:fa:40:85
[ 5179.360462] 80211> EncrypType = 6
[ 5189.365254] 80211> CFG80211_OpsDisconnect ==>
[ 5189.365258] 80211> ReasonCode = 3
[ 5189.471796] 80211> CFG80211_OpsScan ==>
[ 5189.497392] 80211> CFG80211_Scaning ==>
[ 5189.497399] 80211> cfg80211_inform_bss_frame
[ 5189.555788] 80211> CFG80211_Scaning ==>
...
```

The access point I would like to connect to; via `iw wlan0 scan`:

```
BSS a4:2b:b0:fa:40:85(on wlan0)
        TSF: 6658656914006 usec (77d, 01:37:36)
        freq: 5180
        beacon interval: 100 TUs
        capability: ESS Privacy SpectrumMgmt ShortSlotTime (0x0511)
        signal: 0.-47 dBm
        last seen: 3912 ms ago
        Information elements from Probe Response frame:
        SSID: CoolBox_5G
        Supported rates: 6.0* 9.0 12.0* 18.0 24.0* 36.0 48.0 54.0 
        DS Parameter set: channel 36
        Country: US     Environment: Indoor/Outdoor
                Channels [36 - 36] @ 17 dBm
                Channels [40 - 40] @ 17 dBm
                Channels [44 - 44] @ 17 dBm
                Channels [48 - 48] @ 17 dBm
                Channels [52 - 52] @ 23 dBm
                Channels [56 - 56] @ 23 dBm
                Channels [60 - 60] @ 23 dBm
                Channels [64 - 64] @ 23 dBm
                Channels [100 - 100] @ 23 dBm
                Channels [104 - 104] @ 23 dBm
                Channels [108 - 108] @ 23 dBm
                Channels [112 - 112] @ 23 dBm
                Channels [116 - 116] @ 23 dBm
                Channels [132 - 132] @ 23 dBm
                Channels [136 - 136] @ 23 dBm
                Channels [140 - 140] @ 23 dBm
                Channels [149 - 149] @ 30 dBm
                Channels [153 - 153] @ 30 dBm
                Channels [157 - 157] @ 30 dBm
                Channels [161 - 161] @ 30 dBm
                Channels [165 - 165] @ 30 dBm
        Power constraint: 3 dB
        HT capabilities:
                Capabilities: 0x9ef
                        RX LDPC
                        HT20/HT40
                        SM Power Save disabled
                        RX HT20 SGI
                        RX HT40 SGI
                        TX STBC
                        RX STBC 1-stream
                        Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
                        No DSSS/CCK HT40
                Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
                Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
                HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-23
        HT operation:
                 * primary channel: 36
                 * secondary channel offset: above
                 * STA channel width: any
                 * RIFS: 1
                 * HT protection: no
                 * non-GF present: 1
                 * OBSS non-GF present: 0
                 * dual beacon: 0
                 * dual CTS protection: 0
                 * STBC beacon: 0
                 * L-SIG TXOP Prot: 0
                 * PCO active: 0
                 * PCO phase: 0
        Extended capabilities: 6
        VHT capabilities:
                VHT Capabilities (0x338001b2):
                        Max MPDU length: 11454
                        Supported Channel Width: neither 160 nor 80+80
                        RX LDPC
                        short GI (80 MHz)
                        TX STBC
                        RX antenna pattern consistency
                        TX antenna pattern consistency
                VHT RX MCS set:
                        1 streams: MCS 0-9
                        2 streams: MCS 0-9
                        3 streams: MCS 0-9
                        4 streams: not supported
                        5 streams: not supported
                        6 streams: not supported
                        7 streams: not supported
                        8 streams: not supported
                VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
                VHT TX MCS set:
                        1 streams: MCS 0-9
                        2 streams: MCS 0-9
                        3 streams: MCS 0-9
                        4 streams: not supported
                        5 streams: not supported
                        6 streams: not supported
                        7 streams: not supported
                        8 streams: not supported
                VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        VHT operation:
                 * channel width: 1 (80 MHz)
                 * center freq segment 1: 42
                 * center freq segment 2: 0
                 * VHT basic MCS set: 0xfffc
        WMM:     * Parameter version 1
                 * u-APSD
                 * BE: CW 15-1023, AIFSN 3
                 * BK: CW 15-1023, AIFSN 7
                 * VI: CW 7-15, AIFSN 2, TXOP 3008 usec
                 * VO: CW 3-7, AIFSN 2, TXOP 1504 usec
        WPS:     * Version: 1.0
                 * Wi-Fi Protected Setup State: 2 (Configured)
                 * Response Type: 3 (AP)
                 * UUID: 12345678-9abc-def0-1234-a42bb0fa4086
                 * Manufacturer: TP-LINK
                 * Model: Archer C7
                 * Model Number: 2.0
                 * Serial Number: 1.0
                 * Primary Device Type: 6-0050f204-1
                 * Device name: Wireless Router Archer C7
                 * Config methods: Display
                 * RF Bands: 0x3
                 * Unknown TLV (0x1049, 6 bytes): 00 37 2a 00 01 20
        RSN:     * Version: 1
                 * Group cipher: CCMP
                 * Pairwise ciphers: CCMP
                 * Authentication suites: PSK
                 * Capabilities: 1-PTKSA-RC 1-GTKSA-RC (0x0000)
        WPA:     * Version: 1
                 * Group cipher: CCMP
                 * Pairwise ciphers: CCMP
                 * Authentication suites: PSK
```

The partially obfuscated contents of `/etc/wpa_supplicant/archerCoolbox5.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
network={
        ssid="CoolBox_5G"
        #psk="xxxxxxxxxx"
        psk=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
}
```

Evidence I disabled random MAC addressing; via `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Power-saving settings; via `cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`:

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
```

Attempting a connection; via `iwconfig wlan0 essid CoolBox_5G && iwconfig wlan0`:

```
wlan0     Ralink STA  ESSID:""  Nickname:""
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:1 Mb/s   
          RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Link Quality=10/100  Signal level:0 dBm  Noise level:0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

The attempt's respective dmesg output; via `dmesg`:

```
[  994.390379] 80211> CFG80211_OpsDisconnect ==>
[  994.390380] 80211> ReasonCode = 3
[  994.426236] ==>mt7610u_chip_onoff(): OnOff:0, Reset= 0, pAd->WlanFunCtrl:0xff000003, Reg-WlanFunCtrl=0xff000003
[  994.429843] receive cmd msg fail(-2)
[  994.429910] tx_kickout_fail_count = 0
[  994.429912] tx_timeout_fail_count = 0
[  994.429912] rx_receive_fail_count = 0
[  997.486662] ==>mt7610u_chip_onoff(): OnOff:1, Reset= 0, pAd->WlanFunCtrl:0xff000000, Reg-WlanFunCtrl=0xff000000
[  997.486872] MACVersion = 0x76502000
[  997.487246] MAC[Ver=0x76502000]
[  997.487250] usb 1-5: loading firmware mt7610u.bin
[  997.492319] usb 1-5: firmware mt7610u.bin loaded
[  997.497995] fw version:0.1.00 
[  997.497997] build:7640
[  997.497997] build time:
[  997.497998] ilm length = 68780(bytes)
[  997.497999] dlm length = 11476(bytes)
[  997.580031] #
[  997.586409] loading fw
[  997.587481] .
[  997.594002] .
[  997.600500] .
[  997.607007] .
[  997.613378] .
[  997.619609] .

[  997.708167] #
[  997.924565] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffac9f03346728!
[  997.924566] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffac9f03346798!
[  997.924567] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffac9f03346808!
[  997.924568] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffac9f033466b8!
[  997.924569] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffac9f03346568!
[  997.924570] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffac9f033465d8!
[  997.924571] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffac9f032d8a60!
[  997.924572] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffac9f032c78e0!
[  997.924573] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffac9f032c7958!
[  997.924573] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffac9f032d8bd0!
[  997.924575] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffac9f032d8980!
[  997.924576] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffac9f032d8b60!
[  997.924587] CfgSetCountryRegion():CountryRegion in eeprom was programmed
[  997.924593] CfgSetCountryRegion():CountryRegion in eeprom was programmed
[  997.924622] cfg_mode=13
[  997.924624] wmode_band_equal(): Band Not Equal!
[  997.925183] 1. Phy Mode = 61
[  997.925184] 2. Phy Mode = 61
[  997.929272] /home/alan/src/mt7610u/chips/mt76x0.c:1708 assert (pAd->TxPower[choffset].Channel == 36)failed
[  997.937018] ERROR!!! 
[  997.937020] E2PROM: WRONG VERSION 0x2, should be 1
[  997.938520] BT Coexistence word [66] = 0000ffff
[  997.939022] 0x24 = 0xffef, 0x0104 = 0x0033ffef
[  997.939023] EEPROM_NIC_CFG1_OFFSET = 0xfd11
[  997.939395] mt76x0_read_tx_alc_info_from_eeprom: EEPROM_MT76x0_TEMPERATURE_OFFSET (0xD1) = 0xf8
[  997.939396] mt76x0_read_tx_alc_info_from_eeprom: TemperatureOffset = 0xfffffff8
[  997.939396] Temperature Tx ALC not enabled
[  997.942801] 3. Phy Mode = 61
[  997.950380] TxPath = 1, RxPath = 1, RFIC=17
[  997.950389] RTMPSetPhyMode: channel is out of range, use first channel=1 
[  997.951770] MCS Set = ff 00 00 00 01
[  997.961729] <==== rt28xx_init, Status=0
[  997.961731] 80211> re-init bands...
[  997.961883] 80211> re-init bands...
[  997.961884] 80211> RFICType = 3
[  997.961885] 80211> Number of channel = 44
[  997.961886] 80211> Number of rate = 12
[  997.961886] 80211> CurTxPower = 0 dBm
[  997.961888] 80211> TxStream = 1
[  997.961889] crda> CFG80211_RegRuleApply ==>
[  997.961890] crda> reset chan/power for 2.4GHz
[  997.961891] Chan 001:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961892] Chan 002:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961893] Chan 003:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961894] Chan 004:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961895] Chan 005:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961896] Chan 006:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961897] Chan 007:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961898] Chan 008:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961899] Chan 009:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961900] Chan 010:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961901] Chan 011:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961902] Chan 012:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961903] Chan 013:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961904] Chan 014:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961905] crda> reset chan/power for 5GHz
[  997.961906] Chan 036:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961907] Chan 038:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961908] Chan 040:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961909] Chan 044:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961910] Chan 046:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961911] Chan 048:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961912] Chan 052:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961913] Chan 054:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961914] Chan 056:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961915] Chan 060:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961916] Chan 062:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961917] Chan 064:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961918] Chan 100:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961919] Chan 104:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961920] Chan 108:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961921] Chan 112:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961922] Chan 116:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961923] Chan 118:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961924] Chan 120:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961925] Chan 124:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961926] Chan 126:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961927] Chan 128:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961928] Chan 132:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961929] Chan 134:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961930] Chan 136:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961931] Chan 140:        power 0 dBm, DFS 1, DFS Type 0
[  997.961932] Chan 149:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961933] Chan 151:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961934] Chan 153:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961935] Chan 157:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961936] Chan 159:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961937] Chan 161:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961939] Chan 165:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
[  997.961939] Chan 167 (frq 5835):     not allowed!
[  997.961940] Chan 169 (frq 5845):     not allowed!
[  997.961941] Chan 171 (frq 5855):     not allowed!
[  997.961942] Chan 173 (frq 5865):     not allowed!
[  997.961943] Chan 184 (frq 4920):     not allowed!
[  997.961944] Chan 188 (frq 4940):     not allowed!
[  997.961944] Chan 192 (frq 4960):     not allowed!
[  997.961945] Chan 196 (frq 4980):     not allowed!
[  997.961946] Chan 208 (frq 6040):     not allowed!
[  997.961947] Chan 212 (frq 6060):     not allowed!
[  997.961947] Chan 216 (frq 6080):     not allowed!
[  997.961948] crda> Number of channels = 47
[  997.963024] 0x1300 = 00064300
[  997.963025] RTMPDrvSTAOpen(1):Check if PDMA is idle!
[  997.963144] RTMPDrvSTAOpen(2):Check if PDMA is idle!
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf; cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks for replying. I've attached their contents to the bottom of the post. I disabled random MAC addressing previously because I heard that was an issue with 17.04. Do you think this power save setting is causing the issue?

Comment: I think power save is a definite possibility

Comment: Related: [https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u/issues/26](https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u/issues/26)

Answer (score 0):

```
[connection]

wifi.powersave = 3
```

Set it to off with `wifi.powersave = 2`

Because from the source code: `wifi.powersave` can have the following value:

```
NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_DEFAULT (0): use the default value
NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_IGNORE (1): don't touch existing setting
NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_DISABLE (2): disable powersave
NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_ENABLE (3): enable powersave
```