# Cannot install TP-Link AC600 driver

Tags: networking, drivers

Afternoon,

I'm relatively new to Linux and struggling to install the driver for the TP-Link AC600 USB dongle. I'm running 17.04 and Linux kernel 4.10.x.

I've searched through a few forums and this is pretty much my issue: [TP-Link T2U (AC600) usb WLAN adapter driver on Ubuntu 16.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865102/tp-link-t2u-ac600-usb-wlan-adapter-driver-on-ubuntu-16-10)

The comments match exactly my experience, everything works until I run "make install" and receive:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'. Stop.
```

However, this user seems to then move on from that with no obvious solution to that issue? The device has not appeared in Network Manager.

lsusb seems to be showing me the device:

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

Could anyone suggest a few further steps to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The program `make` does the making of the kernel module, `make install` is actually not required here as the follow on step in the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/865157/29073) succeeds in copying the file to the right place with the line:

```
sudo cp firmware/*  /lib/firmware
```

The copy (`cp`) is the installation, `make` doesn't have a configuration file telling it how to do it for you, which it normally would.

Comment: Any further troubleshooting and you should follow the comments in your linked answer. Particularly check `lsmod | grep -i mt76` to make sure the module is loaded and `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e mt76 -e wl` to get details from syslog about what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for your help pbhj.

In the end I rolled back to 16.04 (for other reasons) - the module still wouldn't build until I followed the advice found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/674116/how-to-install-tp-link-t2uh-wireless-adapter-driver-ralink-mt7610u?noredirect=1&lq=1