# TPLink AC600 Driver Install Fails in Ubuntu 16.04 with Unknown Symbol

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, tp-link

I am attempting to install a driver for the TPLink AC600 under Ubuntu 16.04 as outlined in the Answer at this link:

[TP-Link T2U (AC600) usb WLAN adapter driver on Ubuntu 16.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865102/tp-link-t2u-ac600-usb-wlan-adapter-driver-on-ubuntu-16-10)

When running the make command, I get one warning that the frame size of 2040 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes, but no errors.

When I attempt to run the insmod command I get the following error message:

insmod: ERROR: could not insert module mt7610u.ko: Unknown symbol in module

Can anyone help me with this please?

Following are additional items as requested by chili555:

```
kevin@miner01:~$ uname -r
4.10.0-40-generic
kevin@miner01:~$ modinfo ~/Downloads/mt7610u/mt7610u.ko
filename:       /home/kevin/Downloads/mt7610u/mt7610u.ko
firmware:       mt7650u.bin
firmware:       mt7610u.bin
description:    MT7610U 80211.ac usb driver
author:         Hans Ulli Kroll <ulli.kroll@googlemail.com>
license:        GPL
srcversion:     6BAF8B1220487A0F11B9919
alias:          usb:v0E8Dp7650d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc02ipFFin*
alias:          usb:v0E8Dp7630d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc02ipFFin*
alias:          usb:v2357p0105d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0079d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pC711d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v20F4p806Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v293Cp5702d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v057Cp8502d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp0951d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p7610d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p3425d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3D02d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB31d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0075d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p17DBd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p17D1d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp760Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp761Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pB711d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA711d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E8Dp7610d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13B1p003Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp7610d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        cfg80211
vermagic:       4.10.0-40-generic SMP mod_unload
```

After installing the other driver listed in comments:

```
kevin@miner01:~$ iwconfig
enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

ra0       Ralink STA
```

This driver would not automatically connect on reboot.  If I restarted the network manager using `sudo service network-manager restart` then the wireless adapter supposedly connected shortly afterward, but any attempt to actually use the connection failed.

Comment: I also tried manually adding mt7610u.ko under the /lib/modules/$(uname-r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek tree, then running `depmod` and `modprobe mt7610u`.  That seemed to run without any errors, but when I inserted the USB wireless device I got a system error reporting dialogue, and the same thing happened again after rebooting.  So then I ran `modprobe -r mt7610u`, removed mt7610u.ko from the /lib/modules/... tree, and ran `depmod` again.  Now back to where I started...

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `uname -r` and also: `modinfo  ~/mt7610u/mt7610u.ko`

Comment: Additional items added to original question per your request.

Comment: I also tried the driver version provided here: https://github.com/xtknight/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes , and got further.  But I can't yet see how to establish a wifi connection.  Do I need to do something that sets my adapter as "managed"?

Comment: Does it show something other than Managed in `iwconfig`? Frankly, after many experiences with this device, I doubt that you will ever get is to work by any means. See my post #18 here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2367163&highlight=mt7610u

Comment: Added output from iwconfig per your request.  Regarding your other comment, I hope you are wrong, but of course you may not be.  But what I find strange (or hopeful) is that I see other threads (such as the one that I originally tried to follow), where people report getting this thing to work.

Comment: When you read all the comments at the question you linked, does it confirm that the original poster or anyone else actually connected and is happy? I have seen many with earlier, now obsolete kernels; none with 4.4 and later.

Comment: Hmmm, good point.  Well, I guess that pretty well kills using this adapter under Ubuntu.  Problem is that I still need a usb wireless network adapter, and NONE of other the adapters at any of our local retailers appear to work under Ubuntu either (including Netgear, Linksys, ASUS).  Any suggestions?

Comment: See my post #22 here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359573 Remarkably, it is at the point of giving up on yet another mt7610u device!

Comment: As a new ubuntu user, I was blindly following the instructions of various solutions and installers.  I now realize that many of those instructions included things like "apt-get update" and "apt-get upgrade", which among other things, apparently updated the kernel of my 16.04 installation from 4.4.0-101-generic to 4.10.0-40-generic.  At some level, this is almost certainly the reason that some of the driver versions that I tried to use failed to install properly.  So, now I will probably go back and reinstall everything, being much more restrictive of the instructions that I actually follow.

Comment: You can probably simply re-compile the driver while booted into the latest kernel, 4.10.0-40 and `insmod` the driver. If it connects, which I doubt, then it probably will not pass traffic. We will be interested in your result.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading kernel to version 5.0.5 the adapter will work without any third part driver installation.

Here are the steps:

First of all: make backup of all your system and files.

Open a terminal and do the following commands:

```
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.0.5/linux-headers-5.0.5-050005_5.0.5-050005.201903271212_all.deb \\ https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.0.5/linux-headers-5.0.5-050005-generic_5.0.5-050005.201903271212_amd64.deb \\ https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.0.5/linux-headers-5.0.5-050005-lowlatency_5.0.5-050005.201903271212_amd64.deb \\ https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.0.5/linux-image-unsigned-5.0.5-050005-generic_5.0.5-050005.201903271212_amd64.deb \\ https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.0.5/linux-image-unsigned-5.0.5-050005-lowlatency_5.0.5-050005.201903271212_amd64.deb \\ https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.0.5/linux-modules-5.0.5-050005-generic_5.0.5-050005.201903271212_amd64.deb \\ https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.0.5/linux-modules-5.0.5-050005-lowlatency_5.0.5-050005.201903271212_amd64.deb
```

```
sudo dpkg -i  linux-headers-5.0.5-050005*.deb  linux-image-unsigned-5.0.5*.deb  linux-modules-5.0.5-050005*.deb
```

After installation:

```
sudo reboot
```

```
uname -a
```

Tested on Xubuntu 19.04