# How to install driver for TP-Link AC600 USB Wireless on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, tp-link

I want to install a driver for the TP-Link Archer T2UH AC600 (Version 1) USB WLAN adapter on a newly installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Linux kernel 4.4.0).

During compilation I got the error:

> /home/peter/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/cfg80211.h:35:49:
>   error: ‘IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS’ undeclared here (not in a function)
>   struct ieee80211_supported_band Cfg80211_bands[IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS];

so I tried the solutions given in [TP-Link T2U (AC600) usb WLAN adapter driver on Ubuntu 16.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865102/tp-link-t2u-ac600-usb-wlan-adapter-driver-on-ubuntu-16-10?rq=1)
with the following result:

> $ sudo insmod mt7610u.ko
>
> insmod: ERROR: could not insert module mt7610u.ko: Unknown symbol in
>   module

I can not figure out in the other posts what to do next. Anybody?

O! Reading topic [TPLink AC600 Driver Install Fails in Ubuntu 16.04 with Unknown Symbol](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979866/tplink-ac600-driver-install-fails-in-ubuntu-16-04-with-unknown-symbol?noredirect=1&lq=1) I found out that this is a IMPOSSIBLE mission? No TP-Link AC600 works with a kernel 4.4 or higher???

Comment: " I found out that this is a IMPOSSIBLE mission?" Exactly correct. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/975464/mt7610u-unable-to-install-wifi-driver/975504#975504

Comment: Thanks for answering chili555. Maybe I should go back to 14.04 LTS, which uses a kernel 3.13 and try compiling again. This Ubuntu is still supported for a year. Or maybe I better buy a different wireless device. Any suggestions which is a good device to work with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or 18.04 LTS ?

Comment: Please see my post #22 here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359573&p=13639455#post13639455

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano driver for Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149117/tp-link-ac600-archer-t2u-nano-driver-for-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem that you and I have the same usb stick for wireless.
I have published on Github the source mnodified and the process for you get that working on Ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10 with the kernel version for each version where that stick work good.
If you since need that working for you you can attempt that:
https://github.com/Hygens/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/wiki

Verify the correct version for kernels in each version of Ubuntu and be happy.
That is not perfect but functional.

All the best,