# TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano driver for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04, usb

I am looking for a driver for the TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano, on Kubuntu 18.04 (kernel version 4.15.0-51-generic).

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2357:011e TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter

$ inxi -N | grep "TP-Link"
  Device-3: TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter type: USB driver: usb-network
```

I already tried different drivers, none of them worked.

Comment: What did the T2U show for an ID in lsusb?

Comment: @Jeremy31 it shows `Bus 003 Device 010: ID 2357:011e` without any description. I removed any drivers already, though.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

For a more stable driver, try this:

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo make dkms_install
```

If you get error running `dkms_install`:

> `Error! DKMS tree already contains: 8812au-5.6.4.2_35491.20191025`

```
sudo mv /var/lib/8812au /var/lib/8812au-orig
sudo make dkms_install
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of a previous [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1149288/829702)

Comment: I disagree that this answer is a duplicate. It proposes using a different driver repo, `aircrack-ng/rtl8812au`, which is basically upstream of `jeremyb31/rtl8812au-1` suggested by the other answer. That fork seems less maintained than the one here, so possibly this one might actually even be the better solution.

Comment: At the time the question was asked the aircrack-ng did not support the device.  On 11 Nov 2019 [this commit](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/commit/ae31db1a4ca6545e44cca6d42487b44978d9c4de#diff-d9fabc2042b6273069e114ed620fcb4f) was added providing support

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The repo in this answer really provides a much, much more stable driver.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it has the most up to date drivers.

Comment: This answer works for me with Archer T2U (EU) on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @ByteCommander I also agree with you. Only this one worked on Ubuntu 20.04 for TP Link AC600 Nano USB. And therefore this should be the accepted answer

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This is the best answer and should rank higher than the earlier answer. I tried this with Ubuntu 20 and it works like a charm. You need to unplug and plug back your USB adapter after installing it.

Comment: Adding comment to help people searching in future! This worked 100% for me. 

Running lsusb tells me I have: 

ID 2357:011f TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter 

Which is a TP Link Archer T2U V3 USB WiFi adapter.

Comment: This answer works for me for Jetson Nano with a default image from Nvidia + TP-Link T2U Nano.

Comment: This is awesome. Works for TP-Link Archer T2U Nano.

Comment: It detected/authenticated my wifi after unplugging and replugging, but I had to restart to get the web browser to work.

Comment: For kernel 5 and above, use https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au

Comment: I tried the above steps on Ubuntu 20.04, after which I can connect to my mobile hotspot but not yet to my university enterprise wifi network.

I suspect the issue is with the drivers because, for another wifi adapter (TL-WN725N), I'm able to connect to my univ wifi on the same computer.

Comment: @DavidWu aircrack-ng repo works, at least with 5.4.x

Comment: It didn't work for me as is, I had to run the following before: `sudo apt install dkms git build-essential libelf-dev linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: **NOTE:** To anyone else who stumbles over this topic, the latest code in the `aircrack-ng` fork has a weird issue w/ TP Link AC600 T2U Nano adapters, currently. See [this](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/issues/969) issue for a potential workaround.

Comment: Any reason why this isn't in distros? Is there anything the user should be aware of before installing the driver from this fork?

Comment: This didn't work for me, but only because I didn't realise it was a lower case "L" and not a "1". As in, I thought it was lower case "RT18812" not "RTL8812". Fonts need to make the distinction clearer!

Comment: @FlavioOliveira Saved my day! Tried updating kernel, disabling secure boot and installing iwlwifi, nothing happened. But, this worked like a charm!

Comment: Anybody knows if this stick (Archer T2U Nano) runs out of the box with Ubuntu 22.04? Or do I need to install this driver like explained? Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

For the T2U with ID 2357:011e do

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8812au-1.git
cd rtl8812au-1
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Secure Boot will need to be disabled.  The github repo name is a little misleading as the source code supports rtl8812au, rtl8814au, and rtl8821au

With recent changes you will need to

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo make dkms_install
```

This code doesn't include the rtl8814au for that you need

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8814au.git
cd rtl8814au
sudo make dkms_install
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I updated the question to fit the answer.

Comment: I found I had to run `chmod 777 *` before `sudo ./dkms-install.sh` to make everything executable, maybe because I had pre-extracted the .zip file onto a flash drive to bring it to the PC with the WiFi adapter.

Comment: This worked for me, for a TP-LINK AC600, ARCHER T2U Nano, on 19.04, purchased from amazon UK yesterday. No need to chmod anything. THANK YOU

Comment: it worked for me. after installing this driver like this, I enabled the wireless interface as described at https://askubuntu.com/posts/833894/revisions

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly.

I documented my process here: https://gist.github.com/electron0zero/de0eaa13336042bad347f4dbd8749609

Comment: Seeing the following error..

ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 5.3.4 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-47-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/make.log for more information.
Finished running dkms install steps.

Comment: `cd rtl8812au-1 && sudo ./dkms-remove.sh` then see https://askubuntu.com/a/1185986/300665

Comment: @Jeremy31 It's not working

Comment: I was able to get it working following these directions, but I was not able to get the adapter to see networks on the 5GHz band. I opened a new question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324997/tp-link-t2u-plus-5ghz-band

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link that addressed issues I was having thanks to an update from Jags:
[Driver for the TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano, on Kubuntu 18.04 Previous fix from June 6 didn't work for me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1215442/driver-for-the-tp-link-ac600-archer-t2u-nano-on-kubuntu-18-04-previous-fix-from)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dkms

git clone -b v5.6.4.2 https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git

cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Comment: Thanks! I have Ubuntu 18.04 with a Lenovo Y510P and worked with this one.

Answer (score 1):

For the TP-link AC600 Archer T2Uv3 (2357:011f): choose v5.6.4.2 of the driver from aircrack-ng.  With the stable v5.3.4 it seems to function correctly, but disconnects randomly every ~5 minutes. (Ubuntu 16.04)