# TP-Link Archer T2U Nano AC600 not working after upgrade to 19.10

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 19.10, tp-link

In Ubuntu 19.04 I managed to get the TP-Link Archer T2U Nano AC600 WiFi adapter working using [TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano driver for Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149117/tp-link-ac600-archer-t2u-nano-driver-for-ubuntu-18-04) .

After upgrading to 19.10, it no longer works.  I removed the old kernel module and recompiled for the new kernel (5.3.0-19) ignoring the incompatible pointer type warning and did a make install.  It didn't work and I find the errors listed at the end in the boot log.

What do I need to do to get it to work?

```
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: WARNING: CPU: 6 PID: 588 at net/wireless/core.c:868 wiphy_register.cold+0xe4/0x2e5 [cfg80211]
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: Modules linked in: snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event intel_rapl_msr mei_hdcp snd_rawmidi intel_rapl_common x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_seq coretemp snd_seq_device 88XXau(OE+) snd_timer kvm_intel dell_wmi kvm snd irqbypass dell_smbios cfg80211 dcdbas mei_me input_leds intel_cstate dell_wmi_aio joydev serio_raw intel_wmi_thunderbolt idma64 intel_rapl_perf dell_wmi_descriptor sparse_keymap wmi_bmof soundcore mei virt_dma mac_hid acpi_pad sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs zstd_compress raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor hid_generic usbhid hid raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 aesni_intel i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper aes_x86_64 crypto_simd syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt cryptd fb_sys_fops e1000e glue_helper psmouse drm i2c_i801 ahci intel_lpss_pci libahci intel_lpss wmi video
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: CPU: 6 PID: 588 Comm: systemd-udevd Tainted: G           OE     5.3.0-19-generic #20-Ubuntu
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: Hardware name: Dell Inc. OptiPlex 7050/0XHGV1, BIOS 1.12.1 05/09/2019
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RIP: 0010:wiphy_register.cold+0xe4/0x2e5 [cfg80211]
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: Code: ff e9 ea 55 fa ff 48 c7 c7 08 d0 95 c0 e8 2e 31 bb d7 0f 0b b8 ea ff ff ff e9 d2 55 fa ff 48 c7 c7 08 d0 95 c0 e8 16 31 bb d7 <0f> 0b b8 ea ff ff ff e9 ba 55 fa ff 48 c7 c7 08 d0 95 c0 e8 fe 30
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffaeb100757910 EFLAGS: 00010246
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RAX: 0000000000000024 RBX: 000000000000034e RCX: 0000000000000000
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff936bddb97448 RDI: ffff936bddb97448
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RBP: ffffaeb100757988 R08: ffff936bddb97448 R09: ffffffff99f827a4
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: R10: 0000000000000351 R11: 000000000002f9a0 R12: ffff936bd8d5bb00
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffffaeb1003d84b0 R15: ffffaeb1003d5000
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: FS:  00007f973f595880(0000) GS:ffff936bddb80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: CR2: 000055c85e54a128 CR3: 000000040b404001 CR4: 00000000003606e0
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: Call Trace:
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  ? __kmalloc+0x180/0x270
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  ? hrtimer_init+0x2c/0x80
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  rtw_wiphy_register+0x1a/0x1d [88XXau]
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  rtw_cfg80211_ndev_res_register+0x15/0x1c [88XXau]
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  rtw_os_ndev_register+0xf1/0x160 [88XXau]
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  rtw_os_ndevs_register+0x9f/0x103 [88XXau]
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  rtw_os_ndevs_init+0x29/0x3d [88XXau]
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  rtw_drv_init+0x2b4/0x377 [88XXau]
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  usb_probe_interface+0xed/0x290
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  really_probe+0xfb/0x3a0
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  driver_probe_device+0x5f/0xe0
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  device_driver_attach+0x5d/0x70
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  __driver_attach+0x8f/0x150
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  ? device_driver_attach+0x70/0x70
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  bus_for_each_dev+0x7e/0xc0
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  driver_attach+0x1e/0x20
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  bus_add_driver+0x14f/0x1f0
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  driver_register+0x74/0xc0
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  usb_register_driver+0x7b/0x120
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  ? 0xffffffffc11af000
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  rtw_drv_entry+0x47/0x1000 [88XXau]
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  do_one_initcall+0x4a/0x1fa
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  ? kfree+0x1ef/0x210
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x163/0x230
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  do_init_module+0x62/0x250
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  load_module+0x10d4/0x1220
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  __do_sys_finit_module+0xbe/0x120
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  ? __do_sys_finit_module+0xbe/0x120
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  __x64_sys_finit_module+0x1a/0x20
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x5a/0x130
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f973fb0894d
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: Code: 00 c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 13 e5 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffc3e6eb7b8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000562779f6ce80 RCX: 00007f973fb0894d
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007f973f9e5cad RDI: 0000000000000006
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RBP: 00007f973f9e5cad R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000562779f6ce80
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: R10: 0000000000000006 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: R13: 0000562779f75110 R14: 0000000000020000 R15: 0000562779f6ce80
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: ---[ end trace d8279375bd0f5460 ]---
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: WARNING: CPU: 6 PID: 588 at /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1607 rtw_os_ndev_register+0xb8/0x160 [88XXau]
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: Modules linked in: snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event intel_rapl_msr mei_hdcp snd_rawmidi intel_rapl_common x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_seq coretemp snd_seq_device 88XXau(OE+) snd_timer kvm_intel dell_wmi kvm snd irqbypass dell_smbios cfg80211 dcdbas mei_me input_leds intel_cstate dell_wmi_aio joydev serio_raw intel_wmi_thunderbolt idma64 intel_rapl_perf dell_wmi_descriptor sparse_keymap wmi_bmof soundcore mei virt_dma mac_hid acpi_pad sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs zstd_compress raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor hid_generic usbhid hid raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 aesni_intel i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper aes_x86_64 crypto_simd syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt cryptd fb_sys_fops e1000e glue_helper psmouse drm i2c_i801 ahci intel_lpss_pci libahci intel_lpss wmi video
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: CPU: 6 PID: 588 Comm: systemd-udevd Tainted: G        W  OE     5.3.0-19-generic #20-Ubuntu
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: Hardware name: Dell Inc. OptiPlex 7050/0XHGV1, BIOS 1.12.1 05/09/2019
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RIP: 0010:rtw_os_ndev_register+0xb8/0x160 [88XXau]
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: Code: e0 ff ff 4d 39 fd 0f 85 81 00 00 00 4c 89 e7 e8 7f 20 d1 d7 85 c0 0f 94 c0 0f b6 c0 eb 7f 48 c7 c7 98 f4 07 c1 e8 dc 4a 51 d7 <0f> 0b e9 85 00 00 00 c6 83 c8 45 00 00 01 e9 86 00 00 00 4c 8d b7
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffaeb1007579c0 EFLAGS: 00010246
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RAX: 0000000000000024 RBX: ffffaeb1003d5000 RCX: 0000000000000000
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff936bddb97448 RDI: ffff936bddb97448
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RBP: ffffaeb1007579f0 R08: ffff936bddb97448 R09: 0000000000000004
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff936bdb252000
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffffaeb1003d84b0 R15: ffffaeb1003d5000
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: FS:  00007f973f595880(0000) GS:ffff936bddb80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: CR2: 000055c85e54a128 CR3: 000000040b404001 CR4: 00000000003606e0
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: Call Trace:
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  rtw_os_ndevs_register+0x9f/0x103 [88XXau]
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  rtw_os_ndevs_init+0x29/0x3d [88XXau]
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  rtw_drv_init+0x2b4/0x377 [88XXau]
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  usb_probe_interface+0xed/0x290
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  really_probe+0xfb/0x3a0
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  driver_probe_device+0x5f/0xe0
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  device_driver_attach+0x5d/0x70
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  __driver_attach+0x8f/0x150
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  ? device_driver_attach+0x70/0x70
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  bus_for_each_dev+0x7e/0xc0
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  driver_attach+0x1e/0x20
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  bus_add_driver+0x14f/0x1f0
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  driver_register+0x74/0xc0
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  usb_register_driver+0x7b/0x120
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  ? 0xffffffffc11af000
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  rtw_drv_entry+0x47/0x1000 [88XXau]
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  do_one_initcall+0x4a/0x1fa
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  ? kfree+0x1ef/0x210
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x163/0x230
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  do_init_module+0x62/0x250
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  load_module+0x10d4/0x1220
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  __do_sys_finit_module+0xbe/0x120
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  ? __do_sys_finit_module+0xbe/0x120
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  __x64_sys_finit_module+0x1a/0x20
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x5a/0x130
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f973fb0894d
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: Code: 00 c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 13 e5 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffc3e6eb7b8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000562779f6ce80 RCX: 00007f973fb0894d
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007f973f9e5cad RDI: 0000000000000006
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: RBP: 00007f973f9e5cad R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000562779f6ce80
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: R10: 0000000000000006 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: R13: 0000562779f75110 R14: 0000000000020000 R15: 0000562779f6ce80
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: ---[ end trace d8279375bd0f5461 ]---
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
Oct 23 16:40:44 myname kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same wifi adapter and had the same problem after upgrade to Ubuntu 19.10.

I posted a similar question to yours here on this site, and received an answer from @chili555 that fixed my problem and got my wifi adapter back to working perfectly. Here's the link to my question and @chili555's solution:

[TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano USB wifi adapter not working after upgrade from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190941/tp-link-ac600-archer-t2u-nano-usb-wifi-adapter-not-working-after-upgrade-from-ub)

the needed terminal commands are:

```
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
sudo modprobe 88XXau
```