# TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano USB wifi adapter not working after upgrade from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, 19.10

I have the same problem as posted in this previously posted question: [tp-link ac600 ubuntu not working after upgrade to 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183331/tp-link-ac600-ubuntu-not-working-after-upgrade-to-19-10).

I too had used the solution as posted earlier by Jeremy31 to get the wifi adapter working on Ubuntu 18.04. I then reapplied that "Jeremy31 solution" each time the Ubuntu kernel was updated to get the wifi adapter reworking again. That methodology worked fine up through all kernel upgrades until I recently upgraded my laptop (Lenovo G500S) to Ubuntu 19.10. With the "Jeremy31 solution" no longer working for me, I have googled as best I can, but have been woefully unsuccessful in finding an alternative solution that will allow me to re-employ my wifi adapter in 19.10.

Does anyone have any suggestion, or suggestions, for helping to get my wifi adapter working again?

Thank you very much in advance for any help you may be able to offer.

Comment: Let's start by identifying your exact device. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi Chili. Here is the output from lsusb:                                                
paul@paul-Lenovo-G500s:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:011e TP-Link

Comment: Oops. That should have started as @chili555.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This version compiles perfectly on my 19.10 machine using kernel version 5.3.0-23. The compiled driver covers your device:

```
$ modinfo 88XXau.ko | grep 011E
alias:          usb:v2357p011Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

Please do:

```
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
sudo modprobe 88XXau
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: Thank you so very, very much. I ran these commands in terminal, and my wireless adapter is back working perfectly. This is wonderful, and I am so thankful to you for your excellent and prompt help to me.

Comment: Awesome! If my answer has been helpful, please accept it. The searchers will appreciate it. https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Have done so (took me a while to figure out how to do so). Thanks again.

Comment: About to run dkms install steps...
./dkms-install.sh: line 16: dkms: command not found
./dkms-install.sh: line 17: dkms: command not found
./dkms-install.sh: line 18: dkms: command not found
I have  this problem.

Comment: @SDW_1980 sudo apt install dkms

Answer (score 0):

I tried to comment on chili555's answer, but I don't have enough reputation. So here is the comment:
`https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git` does not contain the file `dkms-install.sh`. But the repository `https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8812au-1.git` does have this file (I tried that solution first after reading it [here](https://suraj.dev/blog/configuring-wireless-usb-adapter-archer-t2u-nano-on-linux), but it didn't work for me).

So I copied the two files `dkms-install.sh` and `dkms-remove.sh` into rtl8812au directory, ran `dkms-remove.sh` first and then `dkms-install.sh`.They worked perfectly. After that, I ran the modprobe command from above, and my adapter started working

Hope this helps somebody