# Wi-fi adapter stopped wortking after Ubuntu update

Tags: 18.04, wireless, realtek-wireless

Couple months ago I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 and wi-fi drivers using this response: https://askubuntu.com/a/1149288 . Yesterday I have updated Ubuntu with it's auto update and today I can't connect to Wi-Fi. In Wi-Fi settings it says "No Wi-Fi adapter found". My wireless network card is TP-Link Archer T2U Nano.

```
➜  ~ uname -r; dkms status
5.3.0-26-generic
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.3.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 5.3.4, 5.0.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
rtlwifi-new, 0.6, 5.3.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `uname -r; dkms status`

Comment: Try the second answer at the same page you linked to https://askubuntu.com/a/1191835/

Comment: It worked! Thanks!