# TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano driver for Ubuntu 18.04 not working

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, wireless, tp-link

My Ubuntu version is 18.04.3 LTS
The laptop is Asus G46V

I followed the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149117/tp-link-ac600-archer-t2u-nano-driver-for-ubuntu-18-04?answertab=votes#tab-top) but with no luck.

Here is the first solution:

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8812au-1.git
cd rtl8812au-1
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

and it gives these errors:

```
About to run dkms install steps...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8812au-5.3.4
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=5.3.0-26-generic KSRC=/lib/modules/5.3.0-26-            
generic/build......(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 5.3.4 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.3.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/make.log for more information.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=5.3.0-26-generic KSRC=/lib/modules/5.3.0-26-        
generic/build......(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 5.3.4 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.3.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/make.log for more information.
Finished running dkms install steps.
```

Here is what is in the make.log:

```
    DKMS make.log for rtl8812au-5.3.4 for kernel 5.3.0-26-generic (x86_64)
    Thu Jan 30 11:59:30 EST 2020
    make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.3.0-26-generic/build         
    M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build O="" modules
    make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-26-generic'
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_cmd.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_security.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_debug.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_io.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_mlme.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_mi.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_wlan_util.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_vht.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_rf.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_recv.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_ap.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/mesh/rtw_mesh.o
      CC [M]          /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/mesh/rtw_mesh_pathtbl.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/mesh/rtw_mesh_hwmp.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_xmit.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_p2p.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_rson.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_tdls.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_br_ext.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_iol.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_sreset.o
      CC [M]         /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_btcoex_wifionly.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_btcoex.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_beamforming.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_odm.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_rm.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/rtw_rm_fsm.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/os_dep/osdep_service.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/os_dep/linux/usb_ops_linux.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/os_dep/linux/xmit_linux.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.o
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1415:22: error: 
    initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  .ndo_select_queue = rtw_select_queue,
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1415:22: note: (near initialization for ‘rtw_netdev_ops.ndo_select_queue’)
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_cfgvendor.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/os_dep/linux/wifi_regd.o
    cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-cast-function-type’
    cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:288: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:9512:25: warning: initialized field overwritten [-Woverride-init]
  .set_monitor_channel = cfg80211_rtw_set_monitor_channel,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:9512:25: note: (near initialization for ‘rtw_cfg80211_ops.set_monitor_channel’)
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-cast-function-type’
Makefile:1655: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-26-generic'
Makefile:1711: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Then I went to the second solution:

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

which yielded no errors, but still "no wifi adapter found"

here is the output of `sudo dkms status`:

```
rtl8812au, 5.3.4: added
rtl8812au, 5.6.4.2, 5.3.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
rtlwifi-new, 0.6, 5.3.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Here is the output of `dmesg | grep 8812`:

```
~$ dmesg | grep 8812
[    5.235103] WARNING: CPU: 7 PID: 414 at /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.6.4.2/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1730 rtw_os_ndev_register+0xd1/0x193 [88XXau]
[    5.514623] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 414 at /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.6.4.2/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:3191 rtw_os_ndevs_register+0xd1/0x10a [88XXau]
```

Hereis the output of `sudo modprobe 88XXau && dmesg | grep -e rtl -e 88XX`:

```
[    5.231861] Modules linked in: snd_hda_intel uvcvideo snd_hda_codec 88XXau(OE+) nouveau(+) btusb snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl crc32_pclmul snd_hwdep i915(+) videobuf2_memops btbcm ghash_clmulni_intel snd_pcm videobuf2_v4l2 btintel snd_seq_midi aesni_intel videobuf2_common ttm bluetooth snd_seq_midi_event aes_x86_64 videodev drm_kms_helper snd_rawmidi crypto_simd ecdh_generic cfg80211(OE) mc snd_seq ecc compat(OE) drm cryptd snd_seq_device glue_helper i2c_algo_bit snd_timer fb_sys_fops syscopyarea snd intel_cstate sysfillrect intel_rapl_perf sysimgblt soundcore mei_me mei lpc_ich joydev input_leds mac_hid asus_nb_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap mxm_wmi wmi_bmof asus_wireless serio_raw sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse ahci libahci atl1c video wmi
[    5.232000]  rtw_wiphy_alloc+0x2c/0x1e1 [88XXau]
[    5.232055]  rtw_cfg80211_ndev_res_alloc+0x23/0x6c [88XXau]
[    5.232105]  rtw_os_ndev_alloc+0x3b/0x77 [88XXau]
[    5.232154]  rtw_os_ndevs_alloc+0x8e/0xe2 [88XXau]
[    5.232199]  rtw_os_ndevs_init+0x12/0x3f [88XXau]
[    5.232243]  rtw_drv_init+0x2b4/0x386 [88XXau]
[    5.232299]  rtw_drv_entry+0x5a/0x1000 [88XXau]
[    5.232380] Modules linked in: snd_hda_intel uvcvideo snd_hda_codec 88XXau(OE+) nouveau(+) btusb snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl crc32_pclmul snd_hwdep i915(+) videobuf2_memops btbcm ghash_clmulni_intel snd_pcm videobuf2_v4l2 btintel snd_seq_midi aesni_intel videobuf2_common ttm bluetooth snd_seq_midi_event aes_x86_64 videodev drm_kms_helper snd_rawmidi crypto_simd ecdh_generic cfg80211(OE) mc snd_seq ecc compat(OE) drm cryptd snd_seq_device glue_helper i2c_algo_bit snd_timer fb_sys_fops syscopyarea snd intel_cstate sysfillrect intel_rapl_perf sysimgblt soundcore mei_me mei lpc_ich joydev input_leds mac_hid asus_nb_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap mxm_wmi wmi_bmof asus_wireless serio_raw sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse ahci libahci atl1c video wmi
[    5.232494]  rtw_wiphy_alloc+0x2c/0x1e1 [88XXau]
[    5.232545]  rtw_cfg80211_ndev_res_alloc+0x23/0x6c [88XXau]
[    5.232593]  rtw_os_ndev_alloc+0x3b/0x77 [88XXau]
[    5.232641]  rtw_os_ndevs_alloc+0x8e/0xe2 [88XXau]
[    5.232689]  rtw_os_ndevs_init+0x12/0x3f [88XXau]
[    5.232737]  rtw_drv_init+0x2b4/0x386 [88XXau]
[    5.232790]  rtw_drv_entry+0x5a/0x1000 [88XXau]
[    5.232937] Modules linked in: snd_hda_intel uvcvideo snd_hda_codec 88XXau(OE+) nouveau(+) btusb snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl crc32_pclmul snd_hwdep i915(+) videobuf2_memops btbcm ghash_clmulni_intel snd_pcm videobuf2_v4l2 btintel snd_seq_midi aesni_intel videobuf2_common ttm bluetooth snd_seq_midi_event aes_x86_64 videodev drm_kms_helper snd_rawmidi crypto_simd ecdh_generic cfg80211(OE) mc snd_seq ecc compat(OE) drm cryptd snd_seq_device glue_helper i2c_algo_bit snd_timer fb_sys_fops syscopyarea snd intel_cstate sysfillrect intel_rapl_perf sysimgblt soundcore mei_me mei lpc_ich joydev input_leds mac_hid asus_nb_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap mxm_wmi wmi_bmof asus_wireless serio_raw sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse ahci libahci atl1c video wmi
[    5.233054]  rtw_regd_init+0x30/0x40 [88XXau]
[    5.233104]  rtw_wiphy_register+0x12/0x1d [88XXau]
[    5.233154]  rtw_cfg80211_ndev_res_register+0x15/0x1c [88XXau]
[    5.233202]  rtw_os_ndev_register+0x10a/0x193 [88XXau]
[    5.233250]  rtw_os_ndevs_register+0x78/0x10a [88XXau]
[    5.233297]  rtw_os_ndevs_init+0x29/0x3f [88XXau]
[    5.233344]  rtw_drv_init+0x2b4/0x386 [88XXau]
[    5.233397]  rtw_drv_entry+0x5a/0x1000 [88XXau]
[    5.233472] Modules linked in: snd_hda_intel uvcvideo snd_hda_codec 88XXau(OE+) nouveau(+) btusb snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl crc32_pclmul snd_hwdep i915(+) videobuf2_memops btbcm ghash_clmulni_intel snd_pcm videobuf2_v4l2 btintel snd_seq_midi aesni_intel videobuf2_common ttm bluetooth snd_seq_midi_event aes_x86_64 videodev drm_kms_helper snd_rawmidi crypto_simd ecdh_generic cfg80211(OE) mc snd_seq ecc compat(OE) drm cryptd snd_seq_device glue_helper i2c_algo_bit snd_timer fb_sys_fops syscopyarea snd intel_cstate sysfillrect intel_rapl_perf sysimgblt soundcore mei_me mei lpc_ich joydev input_leds mac_hid asus_nb_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap mxm_wmi wmi_bmof asus_wireless serio_raw sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse ahci libahci atl1c video wmi
[    5.233578]  rtw_regd_init+0x30/0x40 [88XXau]
[    5.233625]  rtw_wiphy_register+0x12/0x1d [88XXau]
[    5.233674]  rtw_cfg80211_ndev_res_register+0x15/0x1c [88XXau]
[    5.233722]  rtw_os_ndev_register+0x10a/0x193 [88XXau]
[    5.233769]  rtw_os_ndevs_register+0x78/0x10a [88XXau]
[    5.233817]  rtw_os_ndevs_init+0x29/0x3f [88XXau]
[    5.233865]  rtw_drv_init+0x2b4/0x386 [88XXau]
[    5.233919]  rtw_drv_entry+0x5a/0x1000 [88XXau]
[    5.234000] Modules linked in: snd_hda_intel uvcvideo snd_hda_codec 88XXau(OE+) nouveau(+) btusb snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl crc32_pclmul snd_hwdep i915(+) videobuf2_memops btbcm ghash_clmulni_intel snd_pcm videobuf2_v4l2 btintel snd_seq_midi aesni_intel videobuf2_common ttm bluetooth snd_seq_midi_event aes_x86_64 videodev drm_kms_helper snd_rawmidi crypto_simd ecdh_generic cfg80211(OE) mc snd_seq ecc compat(OE) drm cryptd snd_seq_device glue_helper i2c_algo_bit snd_timer fb_sys_fops syscopyarea snd intel_cstate sysfillrect intel_rapl_perf sysimgblt soundcore mei_me mei lpc_ich joydev input_leds mac_hid asus_nb_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap mxm_wmi wmi_bmof asus_wireless serio_raw sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse ahci libahci atl1c video wmi
[    5.234128]  rtw_wiphy_register+0x1a/0x1d [88XXau]
[    5.234178]  ? rtw_wiphy_register+0x1a/0x1d [88XXau]
[    5.234224]  rtw_cfg80211_ndev_res_register+0x15/0x1c [88XXau]
[    5.234270]  rtw_os_ndev_register+0x10a/0x193 [88XXau]
[    5.234319]  rtw_os_ndevs_register+0x78/0x10a [88XXau]
[    5.234366]  rtw_os_ndevs_init+0x29/0x3f [88XXau]
[    5.234415]  rtw_drv_init+0x2b4/0x386 [88XXau]
[    5.234469]  rtw_drv_entry+0x5a/0x1000 [88XXau]
[    5.234542] Modules linked in: snd_hda_intel uvcvideo snd_hda_codec 88XXau(OE+) nouveau(+) btusb snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl crc32_pclmul snd_hwdep i915(+) videobuf2_memops btbcm ghash_clmulni_intel snd_pcm videobuf2_v4l2 btintel snd_seq_midi aesni_intel videobuf2_common ttm bluetooth snd_seq_midi_event aes_x86_64 videodev drm_kms_helper snd_rawmidi crypto_simd ecdh_generic cfg80211(OE) mc snd_seq ecc compat(OE) drm cryptd snd_seq_device glue_helper i2c_algo_bit snd_timer fb_sys_fops syscopyarea snd intel_cstate sysfillrect intel_rapl_perf sysimgblt soundcore mei_me mei lpc_ich joydev input_leds mac_hid asus_nb_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap mxm_wmi wmi_bmof asus_wireless serio_raw sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse ahci libahci atl1c video wmi
[    5.234669]  rtw_wiphy_register+0x1a/0x1d [88XXau]
[    5.234719]  ? rtw_wiphy_register+0x1a/0x1d [88XXau]
[    5.234769]  rtw_cfg80211_ndev_res_register+0x15/0x1c [88XXau]
[    5.234814]  rtw_os_ndev_register+0x10a/0x193 [88XXau]
[    5.234858]  rtw_os_ndevs_register+0x78/0x10a [88XXau]
[    5.234902]  rtw_os_ndevs_init+0x29/0x3f [88XXau]
[    5.234951]  rtw_drv_init+0x2b4/0x386 [88XXau]
[    5.235004]  rtw_drv_entry+0x5a/0x1000 [88XXau]
[    5.235103] WARNING: CPU: 7 PID: 414 at /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.6.4.2/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1730 rtw_os_ndev_register+0xd1/0x193 [88XXau]
[    5.235104] Modules linked in: snd_hda_intel uvcvideo snd_hda_codec 88XXau(OE+) nouveau(+) btusb snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl crc32_pclmul snd_hwdep i915(+) videobuf2_memops btbcm ghash_clmulni_intel snd_pcm videobuf2_v4l2 btintel snd_seq_midi aesni_intel videobuf2_common ttm bluetooth snd_seq_midi_event aes_x86_64 videodev drm_kms_helper snd_rawmidi crypto_simd ecdh_generic cfg80211(OE) mc snd_seq ecc compat(OE) drm cryptd snd_seq_device glue_helper i2c_algo_bit snd_timer fb_sys_fops syscopyarea snd intel_cstate sysfillrect intel_rapl_perf sysimgblt soundcore mei_me mei lpc_ich joydev input_leds mac_hid asus_nb_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap mxm_wmi wmi_bmof asus_wireless serio_raw sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse ahci libahci atl1c video wmi
[    5.235186] RIP: 0010:rtw_os_ndev_register+0xd1/0x193 [88XXau]
[    5.235246]  rtw_os_ndevs_register+0x78/0x10a [88XXau]
[    5.235294]  rtw_os_ndevs_init+0x29/0x3f [88XXau]
[    5.235342]  rtw_drv_init+0x2b4/0x386 [88XXau]
[    5.235395]  rtw_drv_entry+0x5a/0x1000 [88XXau]
[    5.514623] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 414 at /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.6.4.2/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:3191 rtw_os_ndevs_register+0xd1/0x10a [88XXau]
[    5.514623] Modules linked in: intel_powerclamp coretemp mei_hdcp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass snd_hda_intel uvcvideo snd_hda_codec 88XXau(OE+) nouveau(+) btusb snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl crc32_pclmul snd_hwdep i915 videobuf2_memops btbcm ghash_clmulni_intel snd_pcm videobuf2_v4l2 btintel snd_seq_midi aesni_intel videobuf2_common ttm bluetooth snd_seq_midi_event aes_x86_64 videodev drm_kms_helper snd_rawmidi crypto_simd ecdh_generic cfg80211(OE) mc snd_seq ecc compat(OE) drm cryptd snd_seq_device glue_helper i2c_algo_bit snd_timer fb_sys_fops syscopyarea snd intel_cstate sysfillrect intel_rapl_perf sysimgblt soundcore mei_me mei lpc_ich joydev input_leds mac_hid asus_nb_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap mxm_wmi wmi_bmof asus_wireless serio_raw sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse ahci libahci atl1c video wmi
[    5.514686] RIP: 0010:rtw_os_ndevs_register+0xd1/0x10a [88XXau]
[    5.514730]  rtw_os_ndevs_init+0x29/0x3f [88XXau]
[    5.514763]  rtw_drv_init+0x2b4/0x386 [88XXau]
[    5.514800]  rtw_drv_entry+0x5a/0x1000 [88XXau]
[    5.790225] usbcore: registered new interface driver 88XXau
```

When I run `lsusb` I get:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5188 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3404 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 2357:011e  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Please advice, I have been struggling with this for so long!

Comment: "Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/make.log for more information." Did you? What did it report? Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `sudo dkms status` and also: `dmesg | grep 8812` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please also edit your question to show the result of: `sudo modprobe 88XXau && dmesg | grep -e rtl -e 88XX`

Comment: Hi @chili555 , thanks for your reply, when I posted this, I was hoping that you reply my question. 
I edited the question.
By the way I bought TP-LINK USB wifi adapter because I had no luck what so ever with the built in `Product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries`

Comment: Is the Broadcom driver loaded and possibly conflicting? `lsmod | grep wl` Let's remove the incorrect dkms installations and reboot and see if it helps: `sudo dkms remove rtl8812au/5.3.4 --all` and also: `sudo dkms remove rtlwifi-new/0.6 --all` Reboot and run: `dmesg | grep -e rtl -e 88XX` and paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Frankly, I'd much rather troubleshoot the Broadcom!

Comment: I followed your recommendation, but unfortunatly still "no wifi adapter found". Here is the output for `dmesg | grep -e rtl -e 88XX` [https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yG5QpWDzc6/].
I would love to fix the Broadcom, but I tried all the suggetiones I found on this website but with no luck. Should I start a new question for the Broadcom and work in parallel?

Comment: Yes, please start a Broadcom question. The paste shows a very unhappy driver. I notice in the aircrack git that several changes were made in the last few hours. It 'makes' perfectly for me on my 5.3.0-xx kernel. Let's try: `cd rtl8812au` and next: `sudo dkms-remove.sh` then: `git pull` You should see quite a few changes to the file. Next: `sudo dkms-install.sh` After it finishes, reboot and show us: `dmesg | grep -e rtl -e 88XX` Fingers crossed!

Comment: Sorry @chili555 I am back. 
Here is the result https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KhXPXzXk5y/
however, the `sudo dkms-remove.sh` returned `command not found` so I had to change it to `sudo ./dkms-remove.sh`, same for install.sh.
One more note, every time Ubuntu starts it gives me this error window **System program problem detected**

Comment: Here is the question for the Broadcom https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207828/broadcom-wifi-not-working-on-asus-laptop . Appreciate your help :)