# How can I install Broadcom Wireless Adapter BCM4352 802.11ac PCID [14e4:43b1] (rev 03) on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS?

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom, asus

I have Asus G46V laptop running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and when I open WiFi settings, I get this message: **No Wifi adapter found**

I tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590442/how-can-i-install-broadcom-wireless-adapter-bcm4352-802-11ac-pcid-14e443b1-r) but with no luck.

Here is my network card:
`03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: AzureWave BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2123]`

Here is the output of `iwconfig`:

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.
```

and here is the output of `lspci -nn -d 14e4:`:

```
$ lspci -nn -d 14e4:
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
```

I then tried:

```
sudo apt update
sudo update-pciids
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

then `sudo reboot`, but with no luck.

Then, following [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) I removed the installed driver using `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source`. I then installed `sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer`
then

```
 sudo modprobe -r b43
 sudo modprobe b43    
 sudo rfkill unblock all
```

but stil having **No Wifi adapter found**

As a side note, a bought a TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano wifi USB dongle but it is also not working. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206897/tp-link-ac600-archer-t2u-nano-driver-for-ubuntu-18-04-not-working?noredirect=1#comment2026352_1206897) is the question where I try to look for a solution.

I very much appreciate your help.

---

**Edit 1:**

I reinstalled `bcmwl-kernel-source`
and here is the output of `$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: AzureWave BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2123]
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083] (rev c0)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1043:200f]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104065/discussion-on-question-by-hany-tawfik-how-can-i-install-broadcom-wireless-adapte).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem looks like some kernel bug. The `wl` kernel module is not loading for some reason.

Try out if it has been fixed by updating your system by running:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks a million!!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working now. I suspect that the Broadcom will outperform the USB.