# Driver for the TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano, on Kubuntu 18.04 Previous fix from June 6 didn't work for me

Tags: drivers, 18.04, wireless, adapter

[TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano driver for Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149117/tp-link-ac600-archer-t2u-nano-driver-for-ubuntu-18-04)
I could not get this fix to work for me. I am in and out of Ubuntu; it's been at least 5 years since I have worked in Ubuntu and I swear it used to be easier to find drivers and almost anything I needed back then. 
Here's the locations of my t2u:

```
     Bus 002 Device 007: ID 2357:0120
```

When I tried fixes from above I get:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package clone
    E: Unable to locate package https://github.com/aircrack-ng
    E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'https://github.com/aircrack-ng'
    E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'https://github.com/aircrack-ng'
    E: Unable to locate package cd
    E: Unable to locate package rtl8812au
```

or

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    <omitted> 
    E: Unable to locate package clone
    E: Unable to locate package http://github.com/jeremyb31
    E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'http://github.com/jeremyb31'
    E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'http://github.com/jeremyb31'
    E: Unable to locate package cd
    E: Unable to locate package rtl8812au-1
    E: Unable to locate package chmod
    E: Unable to locate package .dkms-install.sh
    E: Couldn't find any package by glob '.dkms-install.sh'
    E: Couldn't find any package by regex '.dkms-install.sh'
```

or

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    E: Unsupported file ./dkms-install.sh given on commandline
```

Any help would be amazing.
I tried using drivers from cd, tp link website, and the fix above.
Thank you.

Comment: hi @joelv I've just posted an answer, with detailed steps, as described in GitHub repo. If you run into any issues, please update your post with error messages. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Jags. No issues. Worked first try. Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could install the latest drivers from this GitHub repo: `https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git`

As per the repo, this is how you can install the drivers using DKMS method:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dkms
git clone -b v5.6.4.2 https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Your USB WiFi adapter should be working now.

Comment: Works! Thank you @Jags!

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
 sudo make dkms_install
```

Without

```
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Because the file dkms-install.sh doesn't exist in the repository.

Comment: I don't see it working after this, the antenna still isn't recognized.