# TP-Link AC600 not working on 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04, realtek-wireless

I am new to Linux and I have been struggling trying to connect my wireless connection with

```
Ac600 Device ID : 2357:0120. (RTL8812au).
```

I found some drivers for my exact same wifi card, but none of them have been successful so far. When I type `Iwconfig`, it tells me no wireless extensions.

Comment: Is Secure Boot enabled? `mokutil --sb-state`

Comment: No it is disabled. How can I enable it?

Comment: Did you try this fix? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1215442/driver-for-the-tp-link-ac600-archer-t2u-nano-on-kubuntu-18-04-previous-fix-from Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Dude, amazing work. Thank you I can finally get my assignments turned in

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.