# build driver for old kernel on new kernel in 18.04

Tags: drivers, kernel

What are the step to build [this](https://github.com/astsam/rtl8812au/tree/master) driver on kernel 5.3.0-46-generic ?

Running the make command on the new kernel give me an error on timer structure on the kernel source code (there has been some change) and I can't go on with this.

So how can I build this on the current kernel ?

Answer (score 1):

You can take rtl8812(14)au driver that is building with new kernels form this repo:

https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au

It has been patched for the 5.3 kernel.

Comment: I know... I've a ALFA AWUS 1900 and in my case this driver is the worst choise... I don't know but it is very slow compared to other drivers, if my connection reach 70Mb/s in download (speedtest) with this one of aircrack i touch almost 20Mb/s in download

Comment: This is exatly same driver, but with additional patches supporting new kernels.

Comment: I don't know man ! In my case the driver is very slow and it seems that the connection isn't stable as the other one... Have you any hint ?

Comment: It is a completely different question. You asked why you couldn't install a driver from a specific github repo, not why the ohter one is slow. There may be a ton of reasons why why Wi-Fi is slower. You can't compare two drivers on  the same system.

Comment: yes you're right it's a different question but it is related to my problem

Comment: You can try this one https://askubuntu.com/a/1149288/167850