# TPLink Archer T2U Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers

I had really big ping problems with games, so my friend said that i should get a new network adapter. I got a TP-Link Archer T2U Plus. I installed drivers I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149117/tp-link-ac600-archer-t2u-nano-driver-for-ubuntu-18-04). It shows up as a device but I cant connect to any networks.

Here`s my lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 041e:4088 Creative Technology, Ltd Live! Cam Chat HD [VF0700]
Bus 001 Device 034: ID 2357:0120 TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 09da:f6f3 A4Tech Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c24b Logitech, Inc. USB2.0 HUB
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 214b:7000  USB2.0 HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 9):

You should try the aircrack drivers.
See https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo make dkms_install
```

Reboot

Comment: After these commands I had to do `sudo modprobe 88XXau` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

dkms_install initially failed "recipe for target failed error 127

on Lubuntu 18.04 32 bit

127 error was simply that dkms was not installed.  Learned this from notes in README.md (created during git clone) and be sure to scroll all the way down to get the full info.  Took quite a while to compile on old T22 Thinkpad. Note that DKMS checks to see if the compile module is unique then inserts it. Rebooted and had wifi bars.

fyi