# No WiFi adapter found after moving from Windows

Tags: wireless, adapter

Just moved from Windows to Linux Ubuntu, it says I don’t have a WiFi adapter when I have a TP-Link Archer T2U Plus plugged in.

I have looked online and most have said things like connect Ethernet and Mobile Tethering when I don’t have access to both of those.

And I have already disabled Secure Boot.

Bus 005 Device 002: ID 2357:0120 TP-Link Archer T2U PLUS [RTL8821AU]
Ubuntu Version 21.04

Comment: You haven't told us your release of Ubuntu, nor how far you got with the TroubleShooting steps (key is identifying your device as that provides the clues to getting it to work; and not the brand/model but chipset used on your tplink archer t2u card) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Devices

Comment: I have the latest release and those troubleshooting guides have not helped me at all.

Comment: Please run `lsusb` in terminal in order to **identify** the device (mentioned on chapter 4 of th troubleshooting guide, by the way). Then please edit your question with the relevant line about your USB WiFi device and your Ubuntu release/version, **exactly as requested in the first comment**. In a nutshell, help us help you.

Comment: I have updated my post, if you need anymore information I’ll be happy to provide it.

Comment: Please see @cabez0n answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233440/tplink-archer-t2u-ubuntu-20-04 If you need a step-by-step, please post back.

Comment: I can’t do git commands because I have no internet access.

Comment: Do you still have the DVD or USB from which you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I have a USB with Ubuntu installed on it, I have tried reinstalling it but no luck

Comment: Reinstalling will not help. However, many of the packages you need (not all) are on the USB. I will propose an answer in a few hours. Please have a blank USB key ready to transfer a few packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking for a proven reliable way to use USB drive as an apt repository and simply apt-get install the prerequisites for the driver. I have, so far, been unsuccessful. I propose another method that will get the prerequisites build-essential and dkms installed.

This method, although it is tedious, will work. The list of deb files you need is this: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/q8DzXnzFNq/

Create a folder on your desktop to hold the files. I suggest:

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/debs
```

Browse the USB drive and look in pool/main/b for build-essential; in pool/main/d for dkms and dpkg-dev; in pool/main/f for fakeroot and so on. Continue until every package on the list I provided is dragged into the debs folder.
Now, back to the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/debs
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Now let’s install the driver. Download this file on some other computer and transfer it to the Desktop of your Ubuntu computer on a USB drive or similar: https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/archive/refs/heads/v5.6.4.2.zip

In the terminal, do:

```
cd ~/Desktop
unzip rtl8812au-5.6.4.2
cd rtl8812au-5.6.4.2
sudo make dkms_install
sudo modprobe 88XXau
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: I’m currently dragging all of these packages to my debs folder but I’ve noticed I don’t have some of the packages you’re listing but…packages like g++-7 I don’t have but I have g++-10, all of the -7 packages I have -10 versions of them. I also have libubsan1 instead of libubsan0. Are these the same or are they different?

Comment: Please use the latest, newest versions of each package on the USB installation device.

Comment: I get the error: modprobe: FATAL: Module 88XXau not found in directory /lib/modules/5.11.0-16-generic when executing the last command you gave

Comment: It works perfectly for me. May we see: `cat /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/make.log | tail -n5`

Comment: It says: No such file or directory for both of them. Did I install something incorrectly?

Comment: Run again: `sudo make dkms_install` and show me the last five lines. If it says it encountered an error and to consult the log, please post the last five lines of the log it refers to.

Comment: It says No rule to make target ‘dkms_install’. Stop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128278/discussion-between-chili555-and-carson07).