# Wifi USB adapter not found Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, internet, wifi-hardware-switch

I have two operating systems: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 on the same PC. When I boot windows 10 - everything works fine. When I load ubuntu 20.04 - it fails to turn on the WiFi adapter. This problem appeared recently, it was working fine before. Very strange is the fact that when I execute the `lsusb` command - it lists correctly the usb wireless adapter. It looks like the adapter is connected and recognized by ubuntu, however it is somehow is turned off internally. When I load the Windows 10 - the wifi adapter start lighting up and blinking, but when loading ubuntu - it is always dark. It was working fine few month ago.

`$ lsusb` output:

Bus 001 Device 002 ID 2357:0120 TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter

I'm not able to connect to the internet from that PC while having the issue. I can't do sudo apt-get update or sudo apt-get upgrade or any other command that requires an active internet connection because the internet is not available ((((

Comment: @waltinator not really. There is nothing realted to the problem to my problem. It looks like the Windows OS is blocking the WiFi adapter. I wanted to know if it's possible to turn the WiFi adapter on from the Ubuntu side.

Comment: The device requires a compiled driver that itself requires several dependencies. Are you able to temporarily use an ethernet connection or else tether your phone? If so, the solution is quick and easy.

Comment: @chili555  nope, I can't connect to the internet at all. The key point is that it worked fine few month ago. Same device, same Ubuntu 20.04 OS, same drivers

Comment: Do you have a directory somewhere on your system named rtl8812au or similar?

Comment: nope, there is no directory with that name.

Comment: Let's see: `sudo dpkg -s build-essential | grep Version`

Comment: that command returns: `Version: 12.8ubuntu1.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That adapter is not supported : https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:2357-0120

Get a small USB one that is, anything marketed as for a Raspberry Pi, for instance will work.

Comment: actually you were right. This hardware has no default drivers. I had to install additional drivers: `rtl8812au` https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233440/tplink-archer-t2u-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the aircrack drivers. See https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo make dkms_install
```