# Wifi will not work on my friend's Latitude D630 after installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

Wifi will not work on my friend's Latitude D630 after installing Ubuntu 20.04.  I have updated the 20.04 to 20.04.6LTS.

I tried...https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233440/tplink-archer-t2u-ubuntu-20-04 at whose advice I ran...

```
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
```

... then I ran (admittedly out of order)...

```
sudo apt install git dkms
cd rtl8812au
sudo make dkms_install
```

I don't think the out-of-order was a problem.  I got believable results to everything with no errors.  However, per advice of bkakilli on May 2, 2021 I went ahead and also ran

```
sudo modprobe 88XXau
```

the path... Activities > Search > Wifi         yields "No Wi-Fi Adaptor found"
For the record, it connects to the internet using cable just fine.
BIOS indicates that Wireless is Enabled.
The D630 has a physical Wifi switch which is ON (after several back-and-forths)
The D630 has 2GB of RAM whereas 4GB is recommended for 20.04.  But similar answers I'm finding do not seem to see RAM as an issue.

Also I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Lenovo G570, admittedly a somewhat newer machine than the D630, but on the G570 Wifi works just fine showing me that my Wifi system is OK.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: The link to the wireless info text file that resulted from running required code is.....    https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/VmW9XWD3zs/

Comment: Does my "wireless-info.txt" file reveal some information which might result in a successful diagnosis?

Comment: Should I keep waiting for someone to analyze my "wireless-info.txt" file?  How long does it take to do that and come back with a diagnosis?

Comment: I decided I should probably answer "No" that this...My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue? .... does not answer my question.  It doesn't at face value, but when someone diagnoses the resulting "wireless-info.txt" file, maybe (hopefully) that will change my answer.