# TP-Link wifi adapter not detecting 5GHz band signal

Tags: networking, 20.04, usb, ubuntu-drivers, tp-link

I have TP-Link T2u nano ac600 adapter with Ubuntu 20.04

I have installed https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git driver
Now adapter is working but detecting only 2.4 Ghz band.
On windows 10 it is detecting 5GHz band and it is working fine.

My kernel Version is 5.11.0-25-generic

Output of `lsusb outputs`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b006 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:011e TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b50d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Truevision HD
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `iwlist chan`:

```
lo        no frequency information.

eno1      no frequency information.

wlo1      13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

enx503eaacdf3ea  13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
```

I have also tried this [TP-Link T2U Plus - 5GHz band](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324997/tp-link-t2u-plus-5ghz-band)  but no help.
What is the problem here?