# Install TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Plus driver for Ubuntu 20.04 from USB

Tags: drivers, 20.04, usb

I can find the driver I'm looking for from other questions: [TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano driver for Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149117/tp-link-ac600-archer-t2u-nano-driver-for-ubuntu-18-04). But they all demand an internet connection, which this device does not have.

Is there a way to put these drivers on a USB from a different - internet connected - device and install them from the USB?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mobile internet. Switch on usb tethering on your phone and connect it via usb cable. you are on

Comment: You assume the OP has a phone that can do that.