# TP-Link AC600 Archer dongle driver cannot operate since 20.04.3 forces UEFI?

Tags: drivers, uefi

I have an TP-Link AC600 Archer dongle. My previous system used Ubuntu 20.04, installed shortly after the OS was released, and I installed the drivers and got them to work correctly through this answer:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1191835/684141

This system does not have a UEFI partition. Only /, swap and /home,

However, I did a fresh install today of 20.04.3 from a live USB on another system and it forces you to install a UEFI partition. As far as I can tell, this dongle driver only works with secure boot DISABLED. But I cannot disable secure boot in 20.04.3 and I HAVE to have a UEFI partition. There is no option to disable secure boot in the ASUS Sabertooth Bios and I cannot do it through Ubuntu either, it always goes back to "enabled".

It seems 20.04.3 is forcing UEFI. How can I get this driver and dongle to work now? Is there no way to disable secure boot to get this to work?

Comment: In my Asus UEFI settings, you can disable secure boot, but the option is not called that. You have to set OS type to "other OS" on the boot settings page and that disables it, iirc. It's very non intuitive. I don't know what Sabertooth is though, so yours may be different.

Comment: @OrganicMarble thank you, I managed to get it disabled. What a weird way of describing it in the BIOS.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. It took me a long time to figure out how to disable it!

Answer (score 0):

After hours of being beside myself, I found the solution to get the driver installed and working. It was because the linked solution in the OP is out of date. A much more up to date solution is here:

https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/forum/topic/184118

> Open the terminal and execute the following commands :
>
> 1. Update the package information :
>
> `sudo apt update`
>
> 2. Install dkms and git :
>
> `sudo apt install dkms git`
>
> 3. Install Build Dependencies :
>
> `sudo apt install build-essential libelf-dev linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
>
> 4. Download the Driver files using git :
>
> `git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git`
>
> 5. Navigate to the Downloaded directory :
>
> `cd rtl8812au`
>
> 6. Install the Driver
>
> `sudo make dkms_install`
>
> if the installation is aborted , execute this command '''sudo dkms
> remove 8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025 --all''' , if errors pop up
> '''Usage: remove / --all'''