# Install driver for wireless usb adapter - TP-link Archer T600U

Tags: drivers, wireless, adapter

I have ubuntu 20.04 installed on my PC. The USB wifi adapter (tp-link Archer T600U) is listed when I cage the command lsusb. But when I try to connect to wi-fi it shows no wifi adapter detected. It looks like I need to install the driver for the same. Can someone give guidance on from where can I get the driver and how to do the installation?

Comment: What kernel are you running?

Comment: Please edit and post the relevant line you obtained from lsusb in order to identify the chipset. Brand/model only are often insufficient because manufacturers release different hardware revisions under the same marque.

Comment: Seems you posted a duplicate question. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149117/tp-link-ac600-archer-t2u-nano-driver-for-ubuntu-18-04 Will probably work for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano driver for Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149117/tp-link-ac600-archer-t2u-nano-driver-for-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: The kernal version is 5.11.0-37-generic. The relevant line of lsusb output: Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:011e TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter.