# Is there a functional driver for Mediatek MT7610 based Wireless USB adapter?

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, ralink

I just purchased an AC600 Mediatek MT7610 dualband WiFi USB adapter. The manufacturer pledges to be supported or compatible with Ubuntu. Nevertheless the driver files that come in the package do not compile or 'make' by following the instructions included.

Additionally, while trying to install it I got my former WiFi adapter disabled. Thanks to a good samaritan in AskUbuntu I got the old driver up and running again and learned the way to recover it. Nevertheless I would like to get the my new adapter installed.

Does someone have an operating driver for this device in Ubuntu or have been able to compile the sources that come with the item?

Once I connect the dongle in a USB port I get the following output from lsusb and dmesg commands:

```
Ubu1:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 15a4:1336 Afatech Technologies, Inc. SDHC/MicroSD/MMC/MS/M2/CF/XD Flash Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0e8d:7610 MediaTek Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c52e Logitech, Inc. MK260 Wireless Combo Receiver
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

And:

```
Ubu1:~$ dmesg
(...)
[    1.272869] rtc_cmos 00:01: setting system clock to 2017-02-11 19:49:42 UTC (1486842582)
[    1.273359] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[    1.273360] EDD information not available.
[    1.273390] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
[    1.384667] ata4: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[    1.404722] ata4.00: ATAPI: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH22NS40, NL02, max UDMA/100
[    1.410723] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=3070
[    1.410725] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.410728] usb 1-4: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[    1.410729] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Ralink
[    1.410731] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 1.0
[    1.428750] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/100
(...)
```

I can provide the drivers that come with the device if needed. But surely someone stumbled on this before and has already resolved the issue.

Whatever clue I can get will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your kind attention.

This is the output of the make command indicated in 'How to install TP-LINK T2UH (...)'

```
Ubu1:~/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916$ make
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/tools'
/home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/tools/bin2h
chipset = mt7610u
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.8.0-37-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-37-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o
In file included from /home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rtmp_os.h:44:0,
                 from /home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rtmp_comm.h:75,
                 from /home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rt_config.h:33,
                 from /home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:28:
/home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/os/rt_linux.h:77:0: warning: "EXT_BUILD_CHANNEL_LIST" redefined
 #define EXT_BUILD_CHANNEL_LIST  /* must define with CRDA */

<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/os/rt_linux.h:98:0,
                 from /home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rtmp_os.h:44,
                 from /home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rtmp_comm.h:75,
                 from /home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rt_config.h:33,
                 from /home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:28:
/home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/cfg80211.h:35:49: error: ‘IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS’ undeclared here (not in a function)
  struct ieee80211_supported_band Cfg80211_bands[IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS];
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c: In function ‘announce_802_3_packet’:
/home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:341:16: warning: unused variable ‘pAd’ [-Wunused-variable]
  RTMP_ADAPTER *pAd = (RTMP_ADAPTER *)pAdSrc;
                ^~~
In file included from /home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rtmp_os.h:44:0,
                 from /home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rtmp_comm.h:75,
                 from /home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rt_config.h:33,
                 from /home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:28:
/home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c: In function ‘STA_MonPktSend’:
/home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:450:35: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
         DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("%s : Size is too large! (%d)\n", __FUNCTION__, pRxBlk->DataSize + sizeof(wlan_ng_prism2_header)));
                                   ^
/home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/os/rt_linux.h:669:16: note: in definition of macro ‘DBGPRINT_RAW’
         printk Fmt;               \
                ^~~
/home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:450:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘DBGPRINT’
         DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("%s : Size is too large! (%d)\n", __FUNCTION__, pRxBlk->DataSize + sizeof(wlan_ng_prism2_header)));
         ^~~~~~~~
scripts/Makefile.build:289: recipe for target '/home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o] Error 1
Makefile:1491: recipe for target '_module_/home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/jorge/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-37-generic'
Makefile:403: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

I hope it brings light into the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: MT7610 and RT3070 are quite different chipsets, several generations apart.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install TP-LINK T2UH Wireless adapter Driver (Ralink mt7610u)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/674116/how-to-install-tp-link-t2uh-wireless-adapter-driver-ralink-mt7610u) <- same chipset, same driver. Follow the instructions in order to download, compile and install a better driver that actually works in Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you CelticWarrior. I tried it but it did not work

Comment: If so you should edit your question and post exactly what you did and what were the results.

Comment: I tried 'How to install TP-LINK T2UH Wireless adapter Driver (Ralink mt7610u)'. The 'make' commad failed with Error 2. I am adding the resulting text to the description. Nevertheless, I am not sure if this dongle is the same as TP-LINK T2UH. My device is a black dongle with a very long antenna.

Comment: Brands/models don't matter. The actual chipset is what matters and drivers and instructions are valid for any dongle with the same chipset.

Comment: @Pilot6 - Is there a new driver than the one you suggested here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/674116/how-to-install-tp-link-t2uh-wireless-adapter-driver-ralink-mt7610u

Comment: Try this ones: https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u. This guy is doing a pretty nice job with several "ac" chipset and this branch was updated some hours ago. Good luck!

Comment: @CelticWarrior This driver should probably be updated for the 4.8 kernel. I did not test it. What about https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/mt7610u-dkms_0.2_all.deb Does it build?

Comment: Thank you guys. You're great..! I will try that as soon as I can. It will take a little while for me to handle it.