# Trouble installing driver for wi-fi adapter

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, mediatek

Bought a AC600 wireless adapter and the driver files for Linux do not compile correctly using 'make' commands.

Output of lsusb is Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0e8d:7610 MediaTek Inc.

Tried to use PPA and it didn't show errors but device still isn't working.

Please help.

Comment: Your post is scanty please add a bit more information so we can all see what the problem might be...

Answer (score 0):

https://askubuntu.com/a/674122

Connect to internet by wire, then run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/Myria-de/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.git
cd mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
make
sudo make install
sudo cp RT2870STA.dat  /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat
```

Reboot.

The dongle should work. The only problem is that you will have to re-install it after each kernel upgrade.

But if you keep the driver folder mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916, then it will be quite easy.

You will need to run only

```
cd mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
make
sudo make install
```

after a kernel upgrade.

It is also possible to install it using DKMS. In this case it will rebuild automatically on kernel upgrades.