# I am trying to download and install a driver for the Archer T2UH wireless USB adapter. Nothing works

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb

I have Ubuntu 4.8.0-52.55-generic 4.8.17.

I have downloaded three different drivers (versions all named mt7610u-something) from this answer forum and none of them will install. Most fail compiling, with problems including

```
error: ‘IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS’ undeclared here (not in a function)
  struct ieee80211_supported_band Cfg80211_bands[IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS];
```

and

```
error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  pChipOps->ChipSwitchChannel = Default_ChipSwitchChannel;
```

Another compiles, but the resulting 'mt7610u.ko' file could not be loaded into the kernel because of an unidentified symbol (not specified).

Is there a working version of the driver? or do I have to return the USB wireless adaptor?

Comment: Please list what answers you followed so we don't duplicate your effort.

Comment: I used "TP-Link T2U (AC600) usb WLAN adapter driver on Ubuntu 16.10" and "How to install TP-LINK T2UH Wireless Adapter Driver (Railink mt7610u" (https://askubuntu.com/questions/674116/how-to-install-tp-link-t2uh-wireless-adapter-driver-ralink-mt7610u?rq=1). I am having trouble finding the third one

Comment: I am in exactly the same position :'(