# Ubuntu Freezes when connecting USB device (Archer T2UH)

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, tp-link

I am trying to get the Archer T2UH WLAN USB adapter to work on my Ubuntu 16.04.

I followed the steps in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/674122/324486). At first I thought my whole system was broken when I rebooted after installing the driver, because it always froze on login screen. I could not even switch to non-graphical mode with ctrl+alt+f1 and the likes. Then I booted into recovery mode and did the installation again. That did not help either, because now the whole thing freezes after login.

(Edit #1: When I am logged in and then plug in the device, I get the following error dialog just before it freezes and I cannot do anything anymore:
[image]
I know, it does not tell much, but I cannot click or press any keys after that, so I cannot show the details.
I also tried to plug it in with all other USB devices disconnected, in case of power supply problem. It does not help.)

(Edit #2: I also tried the driver from [here](https://github.com/chenhaiq/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916). No improvement.)

However, I noticed, that it only freezes, when the USB device is plugged in / connected. So right now, I am writing form the same machine, but without having it plugged in.

I am wondering, whether this could this be a power supply issue, but then the T2UH should simply not work, but not freeze my system, right? So I guess it is a software (driver) issue.

What can I do about it?

I checked GitHub, but for that repository, there seems to be no Issue function available and the last development was a year ago.

Are there any experts here, who could guide me through the process of providing more information, so that I maybe can still get the T2UH working?

## Info

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS 64bit xenial
- USB device: Archer T2UH
- `uname -r`: 4.4.0-78-generic
- `uname -a`: Linux xiaolong-hp-pavilion 4.4.0-78-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 27 15:29:09 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- When does it happen: Issue happens when I plug in the USB device, otherwise machine seems to run fine.

Comment: hey haste das schon probiert: https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/fritz-wlan-stick-ac-430-unterstuetzung/2/#post-7740398

Comment: @db429 Thanks, but unfortunately it leads to the same result on my machine.

Comment: perhaps following might be worth a try: `sleep 5 && dmesg` ; this gives you 5 seconds to plug in the device, before `dmesg` gets called, if it does not help using the graphical interface login in to `tty1`[ctl+alt+F1], and try it there.

Comment: @db429 I tried and: Even in recovery mode (drop to root shell) it will freeze the machine when having the USB plugged in. I am not sure about the `dmesg` part. Do you mean I should redirect the output to a file and time the plugging in in a way, that the error is _just_ logged to file before the system freezes?