# TP Link ac600 driver compiling problem

Tags: drivers, wireless, compiling, make

I'm following the [instructions](http://nl.tp-link.com/download/Archer-T2U_V1.html#Driver)(the instructions are included in the zip) to compile the driver for the TP-Link ac600 wireless adapter but I get this error when executing `sudo make`

`make[3]: *** [/home/jonas/Documents/tplinkac600driver/Archer_T2U_V1_150901                            /Driver/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_usb_util.o] Error 1
Makefile:1524: recipe for target '_module_/home/jonas/Documents/tplinkac600driver/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/UTIL/os/linux' failed
make[2]: *** [_module_/home/jonas/Documents/tplinkac600driver/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/UTIL/os/linux] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic'
Makefile:527: recipe for target 'osutil' failed
make[1]: *** [osutil] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jonas/Documents/tplinkac600driver/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Driver/UTIL'
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2`

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 174f:14e8 Syntek 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lsmod` output:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
mt7610u               638976  0
```

`iwconfig`:

```
enp9s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp8s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"cisco"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 4C:00:82:DF:DF:94   
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:76   Missed beacon:0
```

Ouput of all commands: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I254W.jpg

Comment: Please note that the download page says: "Linux (Kernel version 2.6~3.16)." You are running the much newer kernel version 4.10. This antique will never compile. Let's see if we can find a better way. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you! I added the lsusb output to the question.

Comment: The driver is mt7610u : https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_Archer_T2U Please see my comments at post #18 here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2367163&highlight=mt7610u

Comment: Please see my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/970548/errors-while-making-driver-for-tp-link-t2uh-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/970566#970566

Comment: @chili555 please review my previous answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/970548/errors-while-making-driver-for-tp-link-t2uh-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/970566#970566 and see if it's helpful for the future.

Answer (score 0):

At the suggestion of my colleague @heynnema, let's try, with a temporary working internet connection:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y git
git clone https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u.git
cd mt7610u
make
sudo make installfw
sudo insmod mt7610u.ko
```

We anxiously await your good report.

Comment: It didn't give any errors but do I need to do anything after this to make sure the driver is used by the adapter? Because in `lsmod`it shows the driver but the `Used by` section is empty. I'll add the output to the question

Comment: What does iwconfig report?

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: I also added a link to a screenshot of all the commands executed and their output

Comment: I thought it worked but ubuntu says "device not managed" when I want to connect to a network

Comment: I appears that you have a perfectly good internal device that is connected. Why are you trying to coax this stubborn USB to life? Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep -e mt7 -e rtl`

Comment: I bought this one to be able to capture packets in monitor mode, because my current wireless card doesn't support it. Do you perhaps know one that's easier to use and also supports it?

Comment: the logs don't show anything

Comment: I have no suggestions. Please again see my answer at post #18: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2367163&highlight=mt7610u

Comment: sadly also didn't work

Comment: I think you missed my too subtle point. It is that it isn't *ever* going to work, no way, no how. Sorry.

Comment: @DreamsInHD what is the output of `modinfo mt7610u | grep 761a`?

Comment: @heynnema I already returned it so I can't tell you I'm afraid. Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: @DreamsInHD the modinfo command should still work if you still have the driver installed.

Comment: @heynnema I think you'll want 761A or else grep -i. The output is: `alias:          usb:v148Fp761Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*`

Comment: @chili555 you're absolutely correct. Too bad this driver didn't work. There are other current choices at github, but who knows if they work either. We tried.