# MT7610U - Unable to install wifi driver

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 17.10

I tried to install the driver for my new wifi usb stick with MT7610U Chipset from 7Links but had no luck. I tried to install it via github and from the original sources but always had some compiling errors. I also tried it with wpa supplicant and the wext driver but could not get it running. lsusb tells `Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0e8d:7610 MediaTek Inc.` and iwconfig only shows my old wifi stick and two other ethernet cards.

I'm trying to install the driver on ubuntu 17.10.

Is there any way to get it running and can someone tell me how? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is not possible. Please check [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972275/tp-link-ac600-driver-compiling-problem/972334#972334), and [post #18 here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2367163&page=2&p=13670888#post13670888).

I suggest that you get a different device.