# Trying to install TP Link AC 600 Archer T2UH

Tags: networking, drivers

I have followed the instructions given here:

Currently using version `4.13.0-36-generic` kernel

[How to install TP-LINK T2UH Wireless adapter Driver (Ralink mt7610u)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674116/how-to-install-tp-link-t2uh-wireless-adapter-driver-ralink-mt7610u)

However the problem is when i get to `make` command i get the error

```
In function ‘memcpy’,
    inlined from ‘rt_ioctl_iwaplist’ at /home/dev/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.c:696:2:
./include/linux/string.h:305:4: error: call to ‘__read_overflow2’ declared with attribute error: detected read beyond size of object passed as 2nd parameter
    __read_overflow2();
```

I found [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210/issues/81) as a potential solution:

> [...] I guess that Arch (and maybe other distros too) use different (more pedantic) options to build the kernel and its modules, helping us to find programming mistakes. I am not sure whether this is correct, but you can try this (and please report back whether it worked):
>
> In `os/linux/sta_ioctl.c:549`, replace `addr[0]` with `struct sockaddr` so the line looks like this
>
> ```
> memcpy(extra, addr, i*sizeof(struct sockaddr));
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> memcpy(extra, addr, i*sizeof(addr[0]));
> ```

I applied this solution (changed the lines) but the problem still remains.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/975464/mt7610u-unable-to-install-wifi-driver/975504#975504

Comment: okay so its never going to work, can you tell me which wireless device to buy which WILL work?

Comment: Please see my post #22 here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359573&p=13639455#post13639455

Comment: i ended up getting this, straight plug and play for linux : EDIMAX EW-7833UAC AC1750

Answer (score 0):

[This issue](https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u/issues/43) was opened on kerenl 4.13.0 in [mt7610u git](https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u)

ulli-kroll wrote:

> ```
> FORTIFY_SOURCE is introduced in v4.13 from the kernel self protecting team.
> Need some time to fix this, they are maybe more errors like in this driver on mt7612u
> ```

And later reported that this issue was fixed, and suggested using the up-to-date version of the git:

> Please check current git and close this isssue ..

I'd suggest checking mt7610u git repo - https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u