# How to Install this TP-LINK AC600 v2 driver? Unable to find proper solution!

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, 18.04, additional-drivers

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp. 

lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rndis_host             16384  0
cdc_ether              16384  1 rndis_host
usbnet                 45056  2 rndis_host,cdc_ether
nls_utf8               16384  1
udf                    90112  0
crc_itu_t              16384  1 udf
isofs                  45056  1
rfcomm                 77824  4
cmac                   16384  1
bnep                   20480  2
binfmt_misc            20480  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             204800  0
kvm                   593920  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
aesni_intel           188416  2
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
uvcvideo               86016  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
arc4                   16384  2
btusb                  45056  0
videodev              184320  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
snd_hda_codec_realtek    94208  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
rtl8723be              98304  0
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btcoexist             131072  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                32768  1 rtl8723be
snd_hda_intel          40960  8
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
btintel                16384  1 btusb
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
rtlwifi                77824  4 rtl_pci,btcoexist,rtl8723_common,rtl8723be
bluetooth             548864  33 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
intel_cstate           20480  0
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
mac80211              778240  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
joydev                 24576  0
input_leds             16384  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
ecdh_generic           24576  2 bluetooth
mei_me                 40960  0
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
cfg80211              622592  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
serio_raw              16384  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
shpchp                 36864  0
mac_hid                16384  0
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  1 processor_thermal_device
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
snd                    81920  27 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
hp_wireless            16384  0
acpi_pad              180224  0
int3400_thermal        16384  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
sch_fq_codel           20480  3
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            69632  1 uas
usbhid                 49152  0
i915                 1617920  25
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               147456  0
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
r8169                  86016  0
drm                   401408  16 i915,drm_kms_helper
mii                    16384  2 r8169,usbnet
ahci                   36864  3
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    24576  2 wmi_bmof,hp_wmi
i2c_hid                20480  0
video                  45056  1 i915
hid                   118784  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
```

Now the thing is inside of cd the was a text file said to go to tplink site and install the driver
I have downloaded the proper driver V2....
Then there is a user manual
according to that i was going then..

```
sudo make
make -C UTIL/ osutil
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rupam/Desktop/Driver/UTIL'
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6.util /home/rupam/Desktop/Driver/UTIL/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/rupam/Desktop/Driver/UTIL/os/linux modules
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/rupam/Desktop/Driver/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_usb_util.o
/home/rupam/Desktop/Driver/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_usb_util.c: In function ‘rausb_fill_bulk_urb’:
/home/rupam/Desktop/Driver/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_usb_util.c:425:68: error: passing argument 6 of ‘usb_fill_bulk_urb’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  usb_fill_bulk_urb(urb, dev, pipe, transfer_buffer, buffer_length, complete_fn, context);
                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/rupam/Desktop/Driver/UTIL/include/os/rt_linux.h:40:0,
                 from /home/rupam/Desktop/Driver/UTIL/include/rtmp_os.h:48,
                 from /home/rupam/Desktop/Driver/UTIL/include/rtmp_comm.h:62,
                 from /home/rupam/Desktop/Driver/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_usb_util.c:18:
./include/linux/usb.h:1612:20: note: expected ‘usb_complete_t {aka void (*)(struct urb *)}’ but argument is of type ‘USB_COMPLETE_HANDLER {aka void (*)(void *)}’
 static inline void usb_fill_bulk_urb(struct urb *urb,
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/rupam/Desktop/Driver/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_usb_util.o' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/rupam/Desktop/Driver/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_usb_util.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/home/rupam/Desktop/Driver/UTIL/os/linux' failed
make[2]: *** [_module_/home/rupam/Desktop/Driver/UTIL/os/linux] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic'
Makefile:527: recipe for target 'osutil' failed
make[1]: *** [osutil] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rupam/Desktop/Driver/UTIL'
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

my kernel is 4.15.22
my ubuntu 18.04
my gcc is

```
gcc --version
gcc (crosstool-NG fa8859cb) 7.2.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: This is an old driver, that doesn't build for the 4.15 kernel. You need to find a patched one somewhere. You can search by `148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp. `

Comment: This may still work https://askubuntu.com/questions/674116/how-to-install-tp-link-t2uh-wireless-adapter-driver-ralink-mt7610u

Answer (score 0):

Try this driver. Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

```
sudo apt install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u.git
cd mt7610u
make
sudo make installfw
sudo insmod mt7610u.ko
```

This driver needs taking some care to stay after reboots and kernel updates. But it's not very hard if it works.

Comment: I don't believe modprobe will work without `sudo make install` which the Makefile doesn't support.

Comment: `insmod` can insert from where it is if nothing changed in Ubuntu. Probably modeprobe is not needed. I can make a `make install` statement` and `dkms.conf` if needed.

Comment: Yes I tried them but not worked at all.
My kernel version in 4.15.0
which is probably the reason.
These drivers require 3.+ kernel versions..

If any driver is present for the kernel version 4.15.0-generic
please let me know and also how to run it.

**This issue is old and not at all fixed till now.**

Comment: This driver works for 4.15 kernels.