# Problems configuring my usb ac051 wifi adapter

Tags: wireless

I just bought this usb ac051 wifi adapter because my wireless wifi stopped working presumably because something inside the computer related to the wifi broke.

I followed the instructions and used tar to extract the folder containing all the files I need to edit.

I am stuck because I have no idea where I am supposed to download the kernel source code in the included link.And the rest of the instructions make little sense to me and I keep on getting all kind of annoying errors when trying the rest of the commands that do make sense. I can't list my errors right now because I am so exhausted right now after sitting here for hours trying to make my adapter work. Please help!!!. This is what I found when I typed lsusb

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0b05:17d1 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AC51 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [Mediatek MT7610/Ralink RT2870]

Comment: Let's start by identifying your exact USB device. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I just added it.

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083281/cant-install-driver-for-tp-link-t1u-usb-on-ubuntu-18-04-kernel-4-15-0-36-gener/1083342#1083342 Frankly, I doubt that it will ever work. Can you return the device? Sorry for the discouraging reply.

Comment: I would attempt https://askubuntu.com/a/1058790 as I. Think a few have it working

Comment: Everything was fine until the last step with sudo insmod when it says could not insert module mt7510u.ko unknown symbol in module

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/425180/300665 and post a link to your results

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cR9MqSw8FP/ This is the link containing all the results I hope I get a reply soon

Comment: Try `sudo modprobe mac80211` `sudo modprobe cfg80211` `cd ~/mt7610u` `sudo insmod mt7610u.ko` then does it work?

Comment: You could at least accept my answer as a solution, you posted that it worked in an answer that has been deleted

Answer (score 3):

For now the solution is

```
sudo apt install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u.git
cd mt7610u
make
sudo make installfw
sudo cp mt7610u.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
sudo depmod -a
make clean
```

When a kernel update occurs you will need to recompile

```
cd mt7610u
make
sudo cp mt7610u.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
sudo depmod -a
```

Reboot

I have forked the ulli-kroll github and will work on a dkms solution when I have time.  DKMS will automatically compile the module when a new kernel is installed

DKMS Support:
For those who have already downloaded from the ulli-kroll github do

```
rm -rf mt7610u
```

For new users and ones that have deleted the existing mt7610u directory in /home

```
sudo apt install git dkms build-essential
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/mt7610u.git
sudo dkms add ./mt7610u
sudo dkms install mt7610u/1
cd mt7610u
sudo make installfw
```

Reboot and check BIOS to make sure Secure Boot is disabled.

Comment: the line:
'sudo dkms install mt7610/1' must be 'sudo dkms install mt7610**u**/1' this solution run for me, with kernel 4.15.0-45, but on system shutdown watchdog detect a software error.
At display line ' Stopped raise network interfaces' a soft lookup CPU#0 ( NetworkManager:604)
System must be reboot by press hardware button.
Any solution?