# lsInstall TP-LINK ARCHER T2UH on Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

Linux noob here.
I have been trying to repurpose an old Netbook a DNS and Plex server.
I have managed to setup almost everything now and I am happy with it's functionality.

One drawback of this old Netbook is it's 100Mbps Ethernet port. Especially for transferring media from my desktop.
So, I have this TP-Link T2UH wifi with 5Ghz support and would like to use that instead.
Problem is no matter what I try I can't get it to show up in ifconfig.
It is detected by lsusb as "Ralink Tecnololy, Corp."

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b071 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 2.0M UVC Webcam / CNF7129
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0b05:b700 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. Broadcom Bluetooth 2.1
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I have search for other posts about this and even other TP link models ans tried all drivers.
Some cannot be compiled to errors.
The few ones that can be compiled and installed seem to have no effect. (All the posts are very old and there is no official driver for my Kernerl version)

Here are some details

Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
Kernel :        4.15.0-191-generic

Some help would be much appreciated, as I am out of options now.

Here are some of the errors.

Driver 1 (https://github.com/Myria-de/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.git):

```
USERDATA/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/cfg80211.h:35:49: error:‘IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS’ undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean ‘IEEE80211_NUM_ACS’?
      struct ieee80211_supported_band Cfg80211_bands[IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS];
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                     IEEE80211_NUM_ACS
```

Driver 2 (https://github.com/xtknight/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes.git):

```
 /USERDATA/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes/os/linux/../../os/linux/cfg80211.c: In function ‘CFG80211_OpsScan’:
        /USERDATA/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes/os/linux/../../os/linux/cfg80211.c:456:3: error: ‘return’ with no value, in function returning non-void [-Werror=return-type]
           return;
           ^~~~~~
    
    /USERDATA/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes/os/linux/../../os/linux/cfg80211.c: In function ‘CFG80211_OpsStaGet’:
    /USERDATA/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes/os/linux/../../os/linux/cfg80211.c:735:3: error: ‘return’ with no value, in function returning non-void [-Werror=return-type]
       return;
    
       ^~~~~~
```

Comment: "It is detected by lsusb as "Ralink Tecnololy, Corp." It is shown as a great deal more than that. Please edit your question to show the entire result of that line, We need all those numbers and details to propose an answer. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: The driver *mt76x0u* is included in recent kernel versions by default. The 4.15 kernel included in 18.04 is far from recent. I recommend that you install 22.04 LTS where the wireless should work perfectly.

Comment: I tried that initially, but I was not able.After the initial GRUB screen screen would go black with a blinking cursor. After some investigation I got the impression that was no i386 version that would be compatible with this old device. If that is not the case I am more than willing to install the most recent version. Could you please point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: Ahhhh! the old i386 problem! I see. Did you try this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/674116/how-to-install-tp-link-t2uh-wireless-adapter-driver-ralink-mt7610u Were there any errors? Warnings are probably OK.

Comment: There were errors, each driver version had it's own different errors that I cannot recall by memory. If you really think we will get somewhere I can do it all over again and paste the errors.

Comment: I am at a disadvantage. I have no i386 hardware and connot test. We depend on you. Please try this and report the outcome. https://github.com/rebrane/mt7610u

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. I also tried that one before. In the meantime I have moved to debian wich has i386. Maybe in the future I will get a more modern device and come back to Ubuntu as the support for newbies is very good. I will close this thread.